# Google maps API work only on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I wrote a simple google maps application the other day, everything should be fine, but it works only on emulator. when I actually export it and run on the phone, the google maps wont load and all I see is just empty grid. any experiences? thx

Comment: is ur device connected to a proper internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

You need the developer key. Just follow [THIS](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) tutorial to get it. It will work only in your computer, you cannot use the key in another computer.

Comment: I followed exactly that tutorial, but what do I have to do, when I want to run it on phone?

Comment: If you have compiled it with the key, it will load the maps in google map when you throw the emulator

Comment: yes, the maps loads fine on emulator, problem is, when i try to run it on a phone