# This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services (via Bazaar)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm testing out the new Google Maps API V2 for Android, and I'm getting this message when the app launches:

[image: MainActivity showing error message]

*This is running on an 4.1 emulator.*

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Require OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
          android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
          android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="##myapikey##"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

File MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

File activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Clicking "Update" crashes the app with the following stacktrace:

```
E/Trace(1034): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1034): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2010100 but found 1
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1034): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2010100 but found 1
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1034): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2010100 but found 1
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1034): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2010100 but found 1
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1034): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2010100 but found 1
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1034): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2010100 but found 1
D/gralloc_goldfish(1034): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
D/AndroidRuntime(1034): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(1034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)

E/AndroidRuntime(1034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1034): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
  { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://play.google.com/store/apps/details? \
  id=com.google.android.apps.bazaar flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.c$2.onClick(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've also referenced the Google Play Services project. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

The corresponding bug in Google issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822258) was solved some time ago.

Now you can use Google Maps Android API in emulator and create Virtual devices with Play services as described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46246782/5140781

Comment: Are you using avd with google api or plain android?

Comment: Plain Android, although I just tried switching to the Google API's for 4.1 and it's the same.

Comment: Strangely enough I'm looking at exactly the same problem at exactly the same time. I'm assuming so far that it's because the Google Play Services APK isn't installed on the Emulator. The error is because the app is trying to launch Google Play (the store) to install the APK. It'll probably work fine on a device.

Comment: Yes it looks that way doesn't it? The Google Services setup docs say nothing about installing the Play application though: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: The lack of other references to this problem suggests to me that it's quite a recent bug. I can't help but think I've missed something in the setup but I've been through it a few times now. This would literally take 5 mins to set up on iOS - quite annoying :-(

Comment: @gazreese yes you are right iOS 6 maps are awesome!

Comment: How about the included sample, MapDemo, does that work for you? Mine crashes on the same emulator with a ExceptionInInitializationError

Comment: I've not tried that yet. My next step would probably be to try it on a device but unfortunately my wife's taken my nexus 7 to work. I've got plenty of devices at work so I'm going to try it tomorrow in the office. I'll let you know on here if it works fine. There are other posts with people having trouble on device when it works on emulator though (due to device keys). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682580/google-maps-api-work-only-on-emulator

Comment: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/ - suggests that a new version came out today. Great release Google :-)

Comment: Raised - http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4627

Comment: Well I'm using that new API, I thought you were too?

Comment: Yes, using the new one. I'd move back to the old one but doesn't look possible?

Comment: @soren.qvist [How to set up a fast emulator for Android on Linux?](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20130912/how-to-set-up-a-fast-emulator-for-android-on-linux/)

Comment: check [this updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498283/2826147)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to [a discussion with *Android Developers*](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tyz491d96Ci) on Google+, running the new Map API on the emulator is not possible at the moment.

(The comment is from Zhelyazko Atanasov yesterday at 23:18, I don't know how to link directly to it)

Also, you don't see the "**(via Bazaar)**" part when running from an actual device, and the update button open the Play Store. I am assuming Bazaar is meant to provide Google Play Services on the Android emulator, but it is not ready yet...

Comment: I tried copying the latest GmsCore.apk directly to the emulator but that's not working either.  It probably would work if I knew exactly which APKs to copy from my rooted device.

Answer (score 56):

**UPDATE**

**The Google maps API v2 is now installed on the latest Google system images (api:19 ARM or x86).

So your application should just work with the new images. There is no need to install these files.**

I've been trying to run an Android Google Maps V2 application under an emulator and once I finally got Google Play Services running, I updated my SDK to Google Play Services revision 4, and my emulator wouldn't run my application any more.

I have now worked out how to update my emulator from my transformer tablet. (You won't need a tablet as you can download the files below.)

I used Titanium Backup to backup my [Asus Eee Pad Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_Eee_Pad_Transformer) (TF101) and then grabbed the com.android.vending and the com.google.android.gms [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) files from the backup.

I installed these on an emulator configured with platform: 4.1.2, API Level: 16, CPU Intel/Atom x86) and my Google Maps V2 application works again.

That was all .. none of the other steps regarding /system/app were required.

My application only uses the Google Maps API, no doubt, more steps are required if you use other Google Play services.

New files for latest Google Play services:

- [com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk](https://mega.co.nz/#!OR82UKbT!ualgRzV92D1-6SBD6wUqBKUgBpFoeYBKvotQUB2NWY4)
- [com.android.vending-20140218.apk](https://mega.co.nz/#!GQFDETTb!uWPygDxdTr81cd6QRQx-Iqn-9H6u3MKfMijS10ubkMI)

Same instructions as before: Create a new emulator with any [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit)/[ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), a non-Google API target (versions 10-19 work) and [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) emulation on or off, and then install the files:

```
adb install com.android.vending-20140218.apk
adb install com.google.android.gms-20140218.apk
```

If you are upgrading an existing emulator then you might need to uninstall previous versions by:

```
adb uninstall com.android.vending
adb uninstall com.google.android.gms
```

That's all.

Comment: Doesn't matter if your emulator is x86 or ARM. Platform: 4.2 is fine also.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html. Deveices with Android 2.2 (that is API level 8) should be sufficient as long as the devices also has GL ES version 2.

Comment: I tried installing those files but adb showed me failure message that the files were already installed. I tried reinstalling, then it said the certificates are inconsistent. What should I do then?

Comment: I was able to uninstall pre-installed packages with `adb uninstall com.android.vending` and `adb uninstall com.google.android.gms`. After installing above mentioned packages my application runs but I see `EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented` warning messages in the log and no map is visible in the application. This is, I believe, emulator/GPU issue. My GPU is `Radeon HD6870` and I was running Android 4.1.2 without Google APIs on the emulator.

Comment: Regarding the "EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented" perhaps try "Use Host GPU" under the emulation options.

Comment: If the map appears but has no visible tiles, double-check your api key  is set correctly in the android manifest.

Comment: @Martynas I also have "EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented" and the map still works.

Comment: @strawberryjam You are installing the files on a freshly constructed emulator ?

Comment: @strawberryjam Check your emulator was constructed with the plain "Android 4.2" (or whatever version) rather than the "Google Apis - Api  Level 17" option.

Comment: I found that the google ARM image API:19 Revision:3 just works with maps-v2. But the x86 one doesn't .. weird.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/25685873/968532 , Have you any idea about that ?

Comment: @DanBrough where did you get the files? They are obviously getting outdated, why wouldn't just post url to the source of the most recent updates?

Answer (score 39):

I spent about one day to configure the new gmaps [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) (Google Maps Android API v2) on the Android emulator. None of the methods of those I found on the Internet was working correctly for me. But still I did it. Here is how:

1. Create a new emulator with the following configuration:

[image]

On the other versions I could not configure because of various errors when I installed the necessary applications.

2) Start the emulator and install the following applications:

- GoogleLoginService.apk
- GoogleServicesFramework.apk
- Phonesky.apk

You can do this with following commands:

2.1) `adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`
2.2) `adb shell chmod 777 /system/app`
2.3-2.5) `adb push Each_of_the_3_apk_files.apk /system/app/`

Links to [download APK files](http://www.dropbox.com/sh/20hcf8kxdk19z3c/Ukc8uGnk7p). I have copied them from my rooted Android device.

- [GoogleLoginService.apk](http://www.dropbox.com/s/lfde3juixuy88rg/GoogleLoginService.apk)
- [GoogleServicesFramework.apk](http://www.dropbox.com/s/9kurwyhbbuecaea/GoogleServicesFramework.apk)
- [Phonesky.apk](http://www.dropbox.com/s/9x8924gtb52ksn6/Phonesky.apk)

3) Install *Google Play Services* and *Google Maps* on the emulator. I have an error 491, if I install them from *Google Play* store. I uploaded the apps to the emulator and run the installation locally. (You can use `adb` to install this). Links to the apps:

- [Google Maps](http://www.dropbox.com/s/koo4wiwqg8agy8n/com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk)
- [Google Play services](http://www.dropbox.com/s/bh058hbrelccfsr/com.google.android.gms-2.apk)

4) I successfully run a demo sample on the emulator after these steps. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: I think this method has some unnececery steps. Try my method from one of the other answer with only two apks to install...

Comment: I tried your method, but at load applications to system/app dir adb generated an error saying that it is not enough free space. Creating a new emulator with a large amount of memory did not help. On other versions of the emulator your method did not work.

Comment: In step 3) the install command is `adb install com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk` and `adb install com.google.android.gms-2.apk`.

Comment: And make sure you get a version of google play service that fits your needs. You can download them from http://www.papktop.com/tag/google-play-services-apk.

Comment: Just make sure you are always installing the latest Google Play APK version, because at the current moment, Google Play v2, won't let you install update (giving the nasty 491 error) and this update is required to run Google Maps applications.

Answer (score 29):

I'm answering this question for the second time, because the solution I've tried that didn't work at first now works, and I can recreate the steps to make it work :)

I also had a feeling that lack of Google Play Store is a culprit here, so I've tried to install Google Play Store to the emulator by advice on [this link](http://www.piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html) and [this link](http://blog.apkudo.com/2012/08/08/run-google-play-on-an-emulator-and-pretend-to-be-any-device/) combined. I've had some difficulties, but at the end I've succeeded in installing Google Play Store and tested it by downloading some random app. But the maps activity kept displaying the message with the "Update" button. That button would take me to the store, but there I would get a message about "item not found" and maps still didn't work. At that point I gave up.

Yesterday, I've fired up the same test app by accident and it worked! I was very confused, but quickly I've made a diff from the emulator where it's working and new clean one and I've determined two apps on the working one in /data/app/ directory: com.android.vending-1.apk and com.google.android.gms-1.apk. This is strange since, when I were installing Google Play Store by instructions from those sites, I was pushing Phonesky.apk, GoogleServicesFramework.apk and GoogleLoginService.apk and to a different folder /system/app.

Anyway, now the Android Google Maps API v2 is working on my emulator. These are the steps to do this:

---

Create a new emulator

- For *device*, choose "5.1'' WVGA (480 x 800: mdpi)"
- For *target*, choose "Android 4.1.2 - API level 16"
- For "CPU/ABI", choose "ARM"
- Leave the rest to defaults

These are the settings that are working for me. I don't know for different ones.

---

Start the emulator

---

install [com.android.vending-1.apk](http://www.filedropper.com/comandroidvending-1) and [com.google.android.gms-1.apk](http://www.filedropper.com/comgoogleandroidgms-1) via ADB install command

---

Google Maps should work now in your emulator.

Comment: Here is the link to my blog with the description of what I've tried to make this work http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/2012/12/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/

Comment: Unfortunately google play services revision 4 gives new error: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 2010110

Comment: Ok, if you have play services 4th revision, look at the @danbrough answer, and download apks specified in the comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#comment19100235_13869332)

Comment: note that this works with x86 too, making the emulator much more snappy!

Answer (score 3):

I've created a [(German) description how to get it working](http://linuxchef.blogspot.de/2013/05/google-maps-api-v2-im-android-emulator.html). 
You basically need an emulator with at least API level 9 and no Google APIs. Then you'll have to get the APKs from a **rooted** device:

```
adb -d pull /data/app/com.android.vending-2.apk
adb -d pull /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk
```

and install them in the emulator:

```
adb -e install com.android.vending-2.apk
adb -e install com.google.android.gms-2.apk
```

You can even run the native Google Maps App, if you have an emulator with at least API level 14 and additionally install `com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk`

Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to run an Android Google Maps v2 under an emulator, and I found many ways to do that, but none of them worked for me. I have always this warning in the Logcat `Google Play services out of date. Requires 3025100 but found 2010110` and when I want to update Google Play services on the emulator nothing happened. The problem was that the com.google.android.gms [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) was not compatible with the version of the library in my Android SDK.

I installed these files "com.google.android.gms.apk", "com.android.vending.apk" on my emulator and my app [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) v2 worked fine. None of the other steps regarding /system/app were required.

Comment: those are the files to install: [vending.apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jiban3pq2cgkvo/com.android.vending-108b71f4793186b8fd1768a9cd19bbd5.apk) and [gms.apk](http://uploaded.net/file/bnzl1si4)

Answer (score 2):

This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services. I have tried it for such a long much time, but still I didn't get the map... Only a blank screen is appearing, even if I modified my Google Play Service given by the below comment..

---

Check your play services manifest file and check the version code for the APK file com.google.android.gms. In the below, it is "3136110". Download these APK files and install from a DOS prompt, but before installation run your target emulator.

```
package="com.google.android.gms"
android:versionCode="3136110"
android:versionName="3.1.36 (673201-10)
```

I got these APK files from [this link](http://ge.tt/9x9n4lg).

Answer (score 2):

I solved these problem by doing the following steps:

- **In Emulator:**

  You have to use the latest API `Google APIs(Google Inc.)-API Level
  19`.

  Do the rest of the things placed in the screenshot itself.

  [image]
- **API Key:**

  Create New API Key and Check carefully about Google Map API key and SHA Key.
- **Google Play Services:**

  You have to download the latest Google Play Services
     [com.android.vending-4.8.20.apk](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358540606).In that site if google play
     services wasn't working means you can find a lot of sites in
     internet named `com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk`.

  you can run the Google play Services by using the Command Prompt
     `adb install com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk`.

  **Note:** You have to download the latest Google play services because year by year latest version will be updated in internet.

  **output**:

  [image]

Comment: @JJD I am edited check it out.It will work.Thanks for pointed it.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to ADT 22.0.1, due to Android private libraries, the Google Maps service was giving some error and the app crashed. So I found the solution finally and it worked for me.

Just install the Google Play service library and then go to `google-play-service/libproject/google-play-services_lib` from `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ok76ep7lmav0qf/9XVlv61D2b`. Import that into your workspace. Clean your project where you want to use gogole-play-services-lib and then build it again and go to the *Project* -> *Properties* -> *Java BuildPath* -> select "Android Private Libraries, Android Dependencies, google-play-service"

In Properties itself, go to Android and then choose any of the versions and then choose add and select google-play-service-lib and then press apply and finally OK.

At last, go to the Project -> Android Tools -> Android Support Libraries. Accept the license and after installing then run your project.

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice solution which let you test your app in the emulator and also doesn't require you to revert to the older version of the library. See [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17036337/1241606).

Answer (score 0):

From Android SDK Manager, install:
Extras: Google Play services

Answer (score 0):

```
 just change it to 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.0'
```

this works for me  current version is 10.0.1