# Google Maps Android API V2 check if GoogleMaps are installed on device

Tags: android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

When using Google Maps Android API V2 I'm following the [Google Play Services setup documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to make a check to ensure that Google Play Services are installed, using the following code in my main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
      checkGooglePlayServicesAvailability();

      super.onResume();
}

public void checkGooglePlayServicesAvailability()
  {
      int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
      if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
      {
          Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 69);
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
          dialog.setOnDismissListener(getOnDismissListener());
          dialog.show();
      }

      Log.d("GooglePlayServicesUtil Check", "Result is: " + resultCode);
  }
```

This works fine.  However, I noticed some of the older Android phones I have laying around (mostly running 2.2) were missing both GooglePlayServices as well as the Google Maps app itself.

LogCat will report this error:
Google Maps Android API: Google Maps application is missing.

**Question** - how can I perform a similar check to the one above for the availability of Google Maps on a device?  Secondly, if the user already has Google Maps installed I think the check will need to make sure their installed version is compatible with V2 of the Android Maps API.

**Update**
Here is my setupMapIfNeeded() method which is called at the end of onCreate().  This is where I think I'd want to determine if Google Maps is installed and alert the user, see the else block:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() 
{
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) 
    {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.basicMap)).getMap();

        if (mMap != null) 
        {
            mMap.setLocationSource(this);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(44.9800, -93.2636), 10.0f));
            setUpMap();
        }
        else
        {
            //THIS CODE NEVER EXECUTES - mMap is non-null even when Google Maps are not installed
            MapConstants.showOkDialogWithText(this, R.string.installGoogleMaps);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I just ask whats that 69 you have on the getErrorDialog method paramters ?

Comment: @luiscvalmeida The 69 is just the request code (I chose it).  See the getErrorDialog method in http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#getErrorDialog

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Alright after more poking and prodding I realized I just need to ask PackageManager if google maps are installed.  IMO this should really be included in the Google Maps Android API V2 developers guide...there are going to be lots of devs that miss this case and have frustrated users.

Here's how to check if Google Maps are installed and re-direct the user to the Play Store listing for google maps if it's not installed (see `isGoogleMapsInstalled()`):

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) 
    {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.basicMap)).getMap();

        if(isGoogleMapsInstalled())
        {
            if (mMap != null) 
            {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Install Google Maps");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Install", getGoogleMapsListener());
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public OnClickListener getGoogleMapsListener()
{
    return new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps"));
            startActivity(intent);

            //Finish the activity so they can't circumvent the check
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

I wrote up a short blog post with these details: [How to check if Google Maps are installed and redirect user to the Play Store](http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/check-if-google-maps-are-installed-on-android-if-not-direct-user-to-the-play-store/)

Comment: cheers, did the trick no problem! This really should be part of the APi or at least better documented.

Comment: Glad it's helpful.  I totally agree that it should be part of the API docs at a minimum...why not have something similar to the GooglePlayServicesUtil for maps?

Comment: FYI to people reading this using google maps, the MapFragment class will automatically make sure play services is installed, updated, and turned on.

Comment: This method doesn't work. Currently we can get an instance of `GoogleMap` with `mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)` (`mMap` in your case). `isGoogleMapsInstalled()` returns true even on API 19 emulator without Google Play Services.

Comment: @CoolMind I wrote this answer almost 7 years ago, lots has changed.

Comment: @DiscDev, agree with you. I only wanted to write it for future readers.

Comment: You can no longer do this with Android 11

Answer (score 4):

[From Google guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#intent_requests)

```
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that the GoogleMap is available by calling the MapFragment.getMap() or MapView.getMap() methods and checking that the returned object is not null.

> public GoogleMap getMap()
>
> The GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet ready. This
> can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through
> onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also
> happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play
> services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone
> through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this
> method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

You can read about [verify map availability here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#verify_map_availability).

Comment: Nope, this does not work.  With Google Play Services installed but Google Maps not installed (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) calling MapFragment.getMap() is non-null.  However, none of the tiles will load.  The zoom buttons are present and the view looks like a map, but no map data will download and LogCat reports: E/Google Maps Android API(23235): Google Maps application is missing. I need a way to detect this or users will complain the app doesn't work. Updated question with my setupMapIfNeeded method.

Comment: I have just tried remove google maps and maps works fine in my app. Probably newest google play services allows to use map without google maps.