# Google Play Services - Updated?

Tags: google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Is there any way to check if:

1. The Google Play Service is installed
2. The version of the installed version, is or not the minimum version to run the Google Maps v2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

See this documentation: [GooglePlayServicesUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html)

Specifically,

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context)
```

It might also be a good idea to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13789869/1103584)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is there a way to initiate google play services update on button click.. i.e. open playstore intent with the correct url?

Comment: Take a look at the question I linked to in my answer - that post has a full implementation that does exactly what you're asking.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789869/1103584