# How can I refactor my code in Kotlin without Casting?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to know, How can I write code without activity casting like a fragment?....

--------- A Fragment

```
        tempMainImage.setOnClickListener {
            val message = "how are you today"

            (activity as? MainActivity).let {
                it?.onReplaceTtsFragment(message)
            }
        }
```

---------- MainActivity

```
fun onCloseTtsFragmentLayout() {
        detailFragmentLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    fun onReplaceTtsFragment(message: String) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detailFragmentLayout, TtsDetailFragment.newInstance(message, ::onCloseTtsFragmentLayout)).commit()

        detailFragmentLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

Comment: Instead of casting activity `(getActivity())`  you can either use interface or event bus to replace another fragment from fragment refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007656/10097275

Comment: why do you _not_ want to cast ?

Comment: well, casting doesn't have problem. but I just wanted to try to use lambda interface :)

Answer (score 0):

why not try using `when` block and the `is` keyword.

```
tempMainImage.setOnClickListener {
    val message = "how are you today"

    when (activity) {
        is MainActivity -> activity.onReplaceTtsFragment(message)
        else -> return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` is the kotlin replacement for `instanceof` in java

---

```
tempMainImage.setOnClickListener {
    val message = "how are you today"

    if(activity is MainActivity) {
        activity?.onReplaceTtsFragment(message)
    }
}
```