# Google maps V2 shows blank map in new activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm working on an Android app with Google maps. First I made a separate project with some google maps code. This app works fine. Next I made a new app with two activity in the main activity I have a button and when I press it the second activity starts. In the second activity I have put the code of the first project with minor changes to get the right packet name etc.

When I run the app and press the button the second activity starts but I get a blank map with the zoom buttons. I looked at log and i got the error that now connection with te google servers was made. I checked the api key that I put in the manifest but this was oke. Even generated a new one with the same result. What I'm doing wrong or forgetting?

Below is the manifest file and the second activity code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.datoeter.locater"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <permission
    android:name="com.datoeter.locator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

// Permissions that are needed 
<uses-permission android:name="com.datoeter.locator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.datoeter.locater.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.datoeter.locater.TrackActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_track" >
    </activity>

    // API information
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Omitted API key" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

And the activity code

```
   package com.datoeter.locater;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class TrackActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    //Google map object
    GoogleMap Gmap;

    boolean FirstTime = true;

    //Location variables
    LatLng OldLoc;
    LatLng NewLoc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();           
        }
        else
        {
            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            Gmap = supportmapfragment.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            Gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);    

             // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();     

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        if(FirstTime){
            // Get starting position
            OldLoc = latLng;

            // Add start marker
            Marker Start = Gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(OldLoc)
                        .title("Start")
                        .snippet("You started here")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            FirstTime = false;  
        }
        else{

            // Get new position
            NewLoc = latLng;

            // Draw route (line) from last location to new location on map
             Polyline Route = Gmap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(OldLoc, 
                     NewLoc)
                .geodesic(false));

                // New position will be old position for next change
                OldLoc = NewLoc;
        }


        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        Gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        Gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));     

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well made a really stupid typo that was the error. Spelled locator wrong. Now the code works just fine. Thanks for all the help.

I'm using the Genymotion emulator btw. The emulator that comes with the eclipse bundle doesn't support OpenGL ES V2. Just want to mention this because i had this problem in the beginning and had read that a lot of people have or had this problem.

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double check that the Google Maps app is installed on the device you're running this on?  Your issue sounds very similar to this issue:

[Google Maps Android API V2 check if GoogleMaps are installed on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778965/google-maps-android-api-v2-check-if-googlemaps-are-installed-on-device/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm pretty sure that Google maps app is installed. Because the firste app that with the map code in the main activity workes fine. The same code i use for my new app where i have put the code of the first app in a new activity that is lauched in when i press the button in the main activity. Do i need to add aditional steps when i lauche the second activity in case of google maps?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Google Play Services by Android SDK Manager and then use it by importing it in eclipse as it has the new updates and then add these lines to your manifest file within the  element which are missing from your maifest-

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Uninstall the app from the device and install the fresh version.