# Error using Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This app won’t run unless you update Google Play Services. (via Bazaar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar)

I am trying to show up a map as in Google Maps Android API v2. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/.

When I run the application it shows the message "This app will not run unless you update google play services" in emulator.

I also looked into Google Maps V3 as in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ and it says it can be used in mobile app as well.

Can someone help me resolve problem in v2 and suggest if using v3 can be simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that Google Play Services can't be installed on an emulator and that consequently the Maps API v2 can't be tested on an emulator. This seems to be confirmed by Google people in the following Google+ post

[Google plus discussion](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tyz491d96Ci)

This is disappointing news for me.

Comment: Wrong answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13734937/14731

Comment: @Gili - Perhaps you had better tell CommonsWare that he's got it wrong too, see answer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788795/whats-the-difference-between-real-device-and-simulator-emulator

Comment: @NickT, I don't understand your last comment. How is this link related to my last comment? Did you link to the wrong question by mistake?

Comment: @Gili - The last bullet point of Commonsware's answer also says that the v2 maps  run on the emulator.

Comment: Done. I posted a comment under Commonsware's answer.

Comment: I feel really sorry to those contractors that work in companies that forbid the use of USB devices on their computers, especially ones working in companies that refuse to give contractors Android test devices

Comment: What company makes Android software without allowing USB devices as a policy?