# Google map android API V2 crashed

Tags: android, crash, google-api, android-maps-v2

I want to load the google map API on my android. I try everything I search but it still crash.
this is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidmapsv2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }

}
```

This is my layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Require OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="aaa" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDr9xN8L3sF6W2ZRWmTR7q0lhTeOWhXEfQ" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the key i've got
[image]

This is the libs included (Solved in update)
[image]

and i don't have a real android device, so i install it on emulator in this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734937/1821326)

This is the logcat

```
   01-09 18:05:19.184: E/Trace(1366): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-09 18:05:19.354: W/dalvikvm(1366): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/androidmapsv2/MainActivity; (5)
01-09 18:05:19.354: W/dalvikvm(1366): Link of class 'Lcom/example/androidmapsv2/MainActivity;' failed
01-09 18:05:19.365: D/AndroidRuntime(1366): Shutting down VM
01-09 18:05:19.365: W/dalvikvm(1366): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidmapsv2/com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
01-09 18:05:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1366):     ... 11 more
```

**UPDATED**

i've tried to copy the google-play-services_lib to workspace and red mark disappear
[image]
but it come another error. It missing the google-play-services_lib.jar (the lib folder name + .jar). how to fix it 
[image]
when i click the  google-play-services_lib.jar, the remove button doesn't show up(like picture). However i try remove all Android Dependencies and import the others lib again. now it working, but still crash.

I've tried change

```
MainActivity extends Activity
```

To

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

and the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

it appear another error. help me, now i'm out of solution for this

Finally, i solved my error. It caused by my eclipse (i guess). When you add the library class, it automatically appear "google-play-services_lib.jar", you don't have to do anything. I reinstall Eclipse and everything work fine 
[image]

Comment: just select on `google-play-services_lib.jar`, and remove the library.

Comment: thk you for help me, but i think this some kind of error about libs attach and eclipse. i've tried an example online and it has same error

Comment: @Rahul Patel i'm newbie in stackoverflow. how to do that?
anyway, i've solved my problem by reinstall my eclipse and sdk. it's the problem in import libs google-play-services_lib.jar

Comment: @Fido click on the right button below the `upvote-downvote` button.

Comment: @Rahul Patel tks, i've accept, upvote and update my solution for others people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faces this kind of the problem,when first time coding for the map with API V2.

Just try using the extends  with `FragmentActivity` instead of the `Activity`

you have to copy the project(goolge_play_services) into your workspace and then attach it to your project.  In above image it show the cross red,so select it and remove and then after once again add attach the library with the project.

Comment: i changed from Activity to FragementActivity but it still crash and appear another error

Comment: please install `google play services` into your SDK manager.if not visible then update your ADT plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to use `SupportMapFragment` if `API` version is below 11

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

- **Important**

  Don't forget to extend your **Activity** with ***FragmentActivity***

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy the project(goolge_play_services) into your workspace and then attach it to your project.

What you are doing is importing the project and not checkmarking the copy the project into workspace due to which it showing you wrong mark in added libraries.

So just checkmark the the copy the project into workspace while importing the google_play_services project and then attach it to your project.

Comment: tks, I imported it to my workspace and it appear another error. I've update the error in 1st post, how can i fix it

Comment: Please Check that you have added compatibility jar file to your project and extend your activity with FragmentActivity

Comment: i changed but it appear another error, i've update it on first post. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

As here i can see that you are using the api level 8 and AFAIK the "Fragments" are supported from the 11.

So here you need to use the compatible library of the fragments.

And also make sure that you have also imported the library of the google-play-service in your workspace and added it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the  element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```