# Inflate Error on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to add a Google Map to my application and using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=tr#the_google_maps_api_key) tutorial I generated API code, added all necessary meta data, permissions etc. Whenever i click the button to start a new activity the app crashes on my Galaxy S3

onClickListener

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == Button) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowMap.class));
                }
            }
        });
```

Map class

```
public class ShowMap extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_map);

    }
}
```

show_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Error

```
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appname.subappname/com.appname.subappname.ShowMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at com.appname.subappname.ShowMap.onCreate(ShowMap.java:11)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    ... 11 more
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
03-15 20:14:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(18318):    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ShowMap should extends `FragmentActivity` for this to work not `Activity` , check the examples included in google-play-sevice library for google maps they are a big help.

**Edit**

make sure you are including google-play-service library project, as the exception is `ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`

check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro) link on how to include the library project

Comment: make sure you are including google-play-service library, because the exception in ClassNotFound

Comment: Oh, I got it. It says "Copy the <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project into the source tree where you maintain your Android app projects." But my extras folder does not have a folder as google. I have already downloaded Google Play Services SDK

Comment: @Onur maybe you need to redownload it, check if you have the latest google-play-services

Comment: Found it, added to project using properties>android>library but it still gives an error. I replaced the error stack

Comment: @Onur try using SupportMapFragment not MapFragment in your xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26263/discussion-between-onur-and-saksak)

Comment: I use the API key which has been given first and it worked. I don't know why, but currently there is a different id, which causes "Authorization error"

Answer (score 2):

The class `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` is not found. Check if library `google-play-services_lib` is properly linked to the project.

Comment: Oh, I got it. It says "Copy the <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project into the source tree where you maintain your Android app projects." But my extras folder does not have a folder as google. I have already downloaded Google Play Services SDK

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project question. This can help you with adding the project to workspace.

Comment: I added it to project. They are in the same workspace and i also made library things in my project's properties, but it still gives an error. Error stack is renewed