# Cannot be resolved / Cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I recevied error like cannot be resolved to a type. I'm a beginner at java and i'm attempting to develop an android application. I put a commend sign at the place where i received the cannot be resolved to a type error.

```
       package com.example.majorproject;

       import com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.R;

       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.view.Menu;

       public class MajorProject extends Activity {
   static final //LatLng HAMBURG = new //LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
   static final //LatLng KIEL = new //LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
   private //GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();

    if (//map!==null){
      //Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new //MarkerOptions().position(//HAMBURG)
          .title("Hamburg"));
      //Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(//KIEL)
          .title("Kiel")
          .snippet("Kiel is cool")
          .icon(//BitmapDescriptorFactory
              .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    }

  }
```

Comment: I guess you need to import the classes !

Comment: remove this line from your code: import com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.R;

Comment: I tried removing the import statement but the error is still there. And i'm not clear of what import statement is required as they did not provide any necessary import statement.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting error on the `MapFragment` and `Marker`, then you have some problem with the way you are referencing the `google-play-services` library. Take a look at this blog post I wrote, the 3 first steps will explain to you how to do it properly:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 1):

if you are having problem while referencing google-play-service in eclipse, then place the Google play service lib and your project in same workspace. It works.... and don't forget to add support library.

Comment: This is vague.  Can you provide details of how to include Google Play Service lib?  I assume there is a download or update required.

Comment: @mobibob I just wanted to bring in notice that you need to copy the the library in same workspace while importing the lib for proper work. you can find the details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project on how to setup. :)