# Getting noclassdeffounderror when importing project in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, project

I am trying to import this library in my android project

https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf

I imported it, and then added it to build path, then when I run my app, it crashes with this log:

```
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.twotoasters.clusterkraf.InputPoint
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at com.example.idsconnect.ActivityMap.initClusterkraf(ActivityMap.java:165)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at com.example.idsconnect.AsyncLoadMapLocations.onPostExecute(AsyncLoadMapLocations.java:61)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at com.example.idsconnect.AsyncLoadMapLocations.onPostExecute(AsyncLoadMapLocations.java:1)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-05 17:50:31.268: E/AndroidRuntime(29392):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you adding the library to the build path? In the documentation, it suggests "referenc(ing) it from your app as a library project"

Comment: My project already contains the google play services. The way I import it is first I do file > import > existing android project code. Then I right click my project > android > add reference, and chose the clustering library. After that I am getting errors in my activity where I cannot extend the FragmentActivity and cannot resolve GoogleMap class. Im not sure but I think my google play services library is conflicting with the project I am trying to import because it also has it.

Comment: If you click on the "clusterkraf-master/li..." project in the screenshot above, is the "Is Library" checkbox checked?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you may need to add the Google Play Services library to your project. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project) for more details.

Without having all the details, the problem may be that the `InputPoint` class is importing classes from the `com.google.android.gms`package, which is part of the Google Play Service SDK. So if those classes are not present you are going to run into problems.

Comment: My project already has the google play services added to it, and the project I am trying to import also has it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the `google-play-services.jar` in addition to the google-play-services_lib? I would think that'd all be taken care of clusterkraf library, but it's worth a shot (can found here: `google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar`).

The new Google Maps (v2) integration is such a headache :(