# Android import google play service in eclipse error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

i try to  add  google play service in my app( i mean Google map) i added play service in sdk manager and i imported library in eclipse but i  library contains errors.in eclipse  has error
and also in console i have like this  message
"google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'"
but i downloaded and installed 
Android API version from adt 9
java build Path > Android Dependencies.how i can  solve this problem ? what is a solution if anyone knows solution help me
 P.S
i 'm new user in this site
welcome
[this is a result](http://postimg.org/image/h2mahru3x/)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on google-play-services_lib projects and select properties and change the target od project

Comment: i  also tryed this but this is not solution :(

Comment: delete the project and then import again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have **project.properties** in the project. It's needed by eclipse.
If you don't have it, kindly copy it from another existing android project, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your google-play-services_lib project. Check the property of your library project which may have error in **java build path**. You have to tick the **google-play-service.jar** in **Order and Export** tab.