# eclipse android can not import google play services library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

hello i am quite new to Android development and i want to learn how to use the google Maps API v2. After trying numerous tutorials, i always seem to have a problem with the google play services library. Somehow, Eclipse can't  import it properly. I tried this tutorial https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide and when i try to include Google Play Services project as a library, first it all goes nice and smooth, i get a green tick in the Project Properties - Android - Library window, but when i close it i still get lots of "can't be resolved to a type" errors. I return to the window where i add the library and i see a red "X" and a question mark under "project" instead of the green tick. I tried several other tutorials and i always have a problem with this library. I like this tutorial and i would really like to make it work. I also tried to manually copy the library folder in the workspace but that didn't work either. I googled like crazy trying to find an answer but i always find something that i tried before (like manually copying the library in the workspace or something similar). I am quite desperate, i really have no idea why it can't just see the library please help. Also this is my first post to StackOverflow so be gentle :)

later Edit (solved):
when i imported the downloaded project, i kept it on the desktop and thats why it didn't work, after i copied it in the workspace everything worked. Thank you all very much for helping a beginner :)

Comment: Your sdk is updated ? Which version you are using?

Comment: Add both project and library project in same disk drive then you won't get this error.

Comment: Does this thread solve your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project

Comment: i am using the latest sdk and eclipse version. Also, my eclipse, workspace folder and library all exist on drive D:

Comment: @Cristi - Check my solution below. You need to put the library to your workspace under `libs` folder.

Comment: @VedPrakash i tried that and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Cristi - See my recent update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing in adding a library in eclipse is to remember that your project and the library project need to be in the same workspace.

To solve this follow below ways,

You can copy the `google-play-services` library project to the same workspace where your main project is there.

else

While importing the library to eclipse remember to check `copy projects into workspace` which will add a copy of the library to your workspace.

[image]

Comment: thanks, i had to copy the downloaded project from the desktop to the workspace

Answer (score 2):

> I see a red "X" and a question mark under "project" instead of the
>   green tick.

**The problem is** -

*The path to your `google play services library` is not same as the path to your project. It is outside of your project. And so is not recognized by simple import.*

**Solution** - *Put the library in the project's `libs` folder.*

**NOTE:** Just putting the library to the `libs` folder is not enough.

After you added your library follow these steps -

1) Go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs..`

2) Now add your recently added jar to the build path from JAR selection process.

3) Go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`.

4) Put a tick mark in the check box against this library name and press OK.

5) Do `Project -> Clean`.

Comment: i put the google-play-services_lib folder inside the libs folder and still didn't work

Comment: @Cristi - You need to do `Project -> Clean` after the addition. Then build your project and check.

Comment: i did a clean and it is set to build automatically so i suppose it should work, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Cristi - Check my update on how to import the library after adding it to `libs` folder.

Answer (score 0):

if your giving google-Play-Service-lib as a references to your project , try to keep your project and the Google-play services lib should be in same drive.

if your project is on C: drive means place Google-play-services-lib in C:

Answer (score 0):

While making the copy of the entire folder `libproject`  containing `google-play-services_lib`  from eclipse import project by selecting the copied `libproject` folder in your working place.

For the rest follow the steps in [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.)

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse**

- Copy the library project at

> **`<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/`**

to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.

- Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click

> **`File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace`**

and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

- After you've added the Google Play services library as a dependency for your app project, open your app's `manifest file` and add the following tag as a child of the `<application>` element:

> ```
> < meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
> android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
> ```

**Android Studio**

- Open the `build.gradle` file inside your application module directory.
- Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services
  eg

> ```
>     ...
>     dependencies {
>         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
>     }
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> ```

Source [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)