# Error in importing Google-play-service into Ecplise

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-play-services

when i import google play service into my ecplise it shows error in appinvite_style.xml file

Error Location : res->values-v21->appinvite_styles.xml

```
<!-- Base preview application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppInvite.Preview.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"/>
```

[appinvite_styles.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKfUh.png)

and also i tried to import appcomport-v7 but it throws the error in that folder too.

API Level :19 (4.2.2)

thanks in advance

Comment: Download latest google play service library and add this project as library in your main project, in my case it works

Comment: What is your compile sdk version?? rightclick project=> dependency; there what is the version  selected??

Answer (score 0):

The important thing in adding a library in eclipse is to remember that your project and the library project need to be in the same workspace.

To solve this follow below ways,

You can copy the google-play-services library project to the same workspace where your main project is there.

else

While importing the library to eclipse remember to check copy projects into workspace which will add a copy of the library to your workspace.

Please refer this：
[eclipse android can not import google play services library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755131/eclipse-android-can-not-import-google-play-services-library#answer-24755309)