# Getting error when import Google Play services errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have an Eclipse project which I want it to be imported inside Android Studio, but got below error:

```
Project foo:C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo\project.properties:
Library reference ..\..\..\..\..\..\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib could not be found
Path is C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo\..\..\..\..\..\..\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib which resolves to C:\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Remove your google play service lib from project and  add   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2' in gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> To develop an app using the Google Play services APIs, you need to set up your project with the Google Play services SDK. If you haven't installed the Google Play services SDK yet, go get it now by following the guide to [Adding SDK Packages](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html).

Here are the steps to make the Google Play services API available to your app in Android Studio:

> **1.** Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
>
> **Note**: Android Studio projects contain a top-level build.gradle file and a build.gradle file for each module. Be sure to edit the file for your application module. See [Building Your Project with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) for more information about Gradle.
>
> **2.** Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services. For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    }
```

> Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.
>
> **3.** Save the changes and click **Sync Project with Gradle Files** in the toolbar.
>
> You can now begin developing features with the Google Play services APIs.

For additional information, you may also visit the following links:

- [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)
- [Android Studio with Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services)
- [eclipse android can not import google play services library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755131/eclipse-android-can-not-import-google-play-services-library)