# GoogleMap class not found?

Tags: android, google-maps

Here's my code , Why GoogleMap class is not importing from library?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class FirstMap extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstmap);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: am sorry what that meant??

Comment: Go to build.gradle and write this - " compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'" and then sync project

Comment: where can i find  build.gradle in my project ?

Comment: No, I am using eclipse with andriod sdk tools .

Comment: Well stop, Eclipse was deprecated in **2014**

Comment: yeah am having a jar file in my lib folder

Comment: see this : [Add Google Play Services to Eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project). You need to add play services to your project for using `GoogleMap`. **I recommend you to switch to Android Studio as it is currently new and trending**

Comment: Sure I will move to AS . The above thread was helpful . Thanks!!