# Application crashes when is executed using Google maps api v2

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to basically load a map using Google maps api v2 so i can start working on a more complex application.
My problem is that i followed all the instructions in:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
to setup the new settings for the google map api v2 that uses Google play lib.
Everything is set up fine but when i run the application it crashes(myapp stoped working)
I am using intellij so the applications was signed through "build|Generate signed apk" and to get my SHA1 code i used the file that is generated when the Generate signed apk is selected. I created a new project in Google console named MapTest to get the api key and placed that in the manifest as specified.
Now i know that the emulators usually are missing some staff such as the openGL ES so i installed the app on my phone (Galaxy s2) and the application is still crashing.
ps the google play lib was added 
Emulator is google api 15 and everything is updated to latest versions.
Any help or input is deeply appreciated.

Bellow i am including my xml files so you can see if there is anything wrong.

main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.MapTest"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my api key goes here"/>

</application>
<permission
        android:name="com.example.MapTest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.MapTest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission             android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
</manifest>
```

MyActivity class
nothing really change tho included just in case

```
package com.example.MapTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   /**
    * Called when the activity is first created.
    */
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

the log of the emulator

```
01-09 22:16:54.269: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1779): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-09 22:16:54.269: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1779): CheckJNI is ON
01-09 22:16:55.766: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1779): Calling main entry   com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-09 22:16:56.059: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1031): GC_EXPLICIT freed 416K, 15% free 11721K/13703K, paused 9ms+19ms
01-09 22:16:56.099: WARN/ActivityManager(1031): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.example.MapTest
01-09 22:16:56.139: WARN/ActivityManager(1031): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.example.MapTest
01-09 22:16:56.379: INFO/PackageManager(1031): Removing non-system package:com.example.MapTest
01-09 22:16:56.379: INFO/ActivityManager(1031): Force stopping package com.example.MapTest uid=10044
01-09 22:16:56.529: INFO/PackageManager(1031): Package com.example.MapTest codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.MapTest-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.MapTest-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
01-09 22:16:56.529: INFO/PackageManager(1031): Running dexopt on: com.example.MapTest
01-09 22:16:57.781: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1790): DexOpt: load 230ms, verify+opt 493ms
01-09 22:16:57.809: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Code path for pkg : com.example.MapTest changing from /data/app/com.example.MapTest-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.MapTest-1.apk
01-09 22:16:57.809: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Resource path for pkg : com.example.MapTest changing from /data/app/com.example.MapTest-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.MapTest-1.apk
01-09 22:16:57.829: INFO/ActivityManager(1031): Force stopping package com.example.MapTest uid=10044
01-09 22:16:57.939: DEBUG/PackageManager(1031): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.MapTest-1.apk
01-09 22:16:57.949: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
01-09 22:16:57.949: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
01-09 22:16:57.959: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.BILLING_ACCOUNT_SERVICE in package com.google.android.gsf.login
01-09 22:16:57.959: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.ADD_CREDIT_CARD in package com.google.android.gsf.login
01-09 22:16:57.959: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Unknown permission com.android.vending.billing.IBillingAccountService.BIND2 in package com.google.android.gsf.login
01-09 22:16:57.959: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Not granting permission   android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser   (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
01-09 22:16:57.959: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x28be44)
01-09 22:16:57.989: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Unknown permission com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps
01-09 22:16:57.989: WARN/PackageManager(1031): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)
01-09 22:16:58.299: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1031): GC_CONCURRENT freed 544K, 15% free   11758K/13703K, paused 9ms+12ms
01-09 22:16:58.489: INFO/ActivityManager(1031): Force stopping package com.example.MapTest uid=10044
01-09 22:16:58.639: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 250K, 7% free 11414K/12231K, paused 5ms+7ms
01-09 22:16:58.869: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1166): GC_EXPLICIT freed 172K, 4% free 9398K/9735K, paused 10ms+9ms
01-09 22:16:59.159: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1031): GC_EXPLICIT freed 191K, 15% free 11704K/13703K, paused 7ms+14ms
01-09 22:16:59.259: DEBUG/PackageManager(1031): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
01-09 22:16:59.409: DEBUG/PackageManager(1031): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
01-09 22:16:59.431: DEBUG/BackupManagerService(1031): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.MapTest flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
01-09 22:16:59.459: DEBUG/PackageManager(1031): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
01-09 22:16:59.479: DEBUG/PackageManager(1031): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
01-09 22:16:59.599: DEBUG/BackupManagerService(1031): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.MapTest flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
01-09 22:16:59.629: VERBOSE/BackupManagerService(1031): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: #1
01-09 22:17:00.642: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(1031): no available voice recognition services found
01-09 22:17:00.889: DEBUG/BackupManagerService(1031): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.example.MapTest flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
01-09 22:17:00.889: VERBOSE/BackupManagerService(1031): updatePackageParticipantsLocked: #1
01-09 22:17:01.519: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1031): GC_EXPLICIT freed 528K, 14% free 11847K/13703K, paused 7ms+17ms
01-09 22:17:02.069: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1779): Shutting down VM
01-09 22:17:02.089: INFO/AndroidRuntime(1779): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-09 22:17:02.089: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 456K/2048K, paused 2ms+4ms
01-09 22:17:02.099: DEBUG/jdwp(1779): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-09 22:17:02.099: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1779): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-09 22:17:02.789: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1795): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-09 22:17:02.789: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1795): CheckJNI is ON
01-09 22:17:03.949: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1795): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-09 22:17:03.989: INFO/ActivityManager(1031): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.MapTest/.MyActivity} from pid 1795
01-09 22:17:04.029: WARN/WindowManager(1031): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
01-09 22:17:04.111: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1795): Shutting down VM
01-09 22:17:04.139: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1806): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-09 22:17:04.139: INFO/AndroidRuntime(1795): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-09 22:17:04.159: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 486K/2048K, paused 1ms+5ms
01-09 22:17:04.159: DEBUG/jdwp(1795): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-09 22:17:04.159: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1795): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-09 22:17:04.209: INFO/ActivityManager(1031): Start proc com.example.MapTest for activity com.example.MapTest/.MyActivity: pid=1806 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1015}
01-09 22:17:04.649: WARN/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(1031): setKernelCountSet(10044, 1) failed with errno -2
01-09 22:17:05.269: INFO/Process(1031): Sending signal. PID: 1806 SIG: 3
01-09 22:17:05.309: INFO/dalvikvm(1806): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-09 22:17:05.429: INFO/dalvikvm(1806): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-09 22:17:05.599: WARN/dalvikvm(1806): VFY: unable to resolve static field 40 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
01-09 22:17:05.599: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1806): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
01-09 22:17:05.609: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1806): Shutting down VM
01-09 22:17:05.609: WARN/dalvikvm(1806): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-09 22:17:05.629: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4242)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    at com.example.MapTest.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-09 22:17:05.649: WARN/ActivityManager(1031): Force finishing activity     com.example.MapTest/.MyActivity
    01-09 22:17:05.659: WARN/WindowManager(1031): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
    01-09 22:17:05.680: INFO/Process(1031): Sending signal. PID: 1806 SIG: 3
    01-09 22:17:05.680: INFO/dalvikvm(1806): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    01-09 22:17:05.699: INFO/dalvikvm(1806): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    01-09 22:17:06.169: WARN/ActivityManager(1031): Activity pause timeout for     ActivityRecord{4146dc60 com.example.MapTest/.MyActivity}
    01-09 22:17:06.209: INFO/Process(1031): Sending signal. PID: 1806 SIG: 3
    01-09 22:17:06.209: INFO/dalvikvm(1806): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    01-09 22:17:06.229: INFO/dalvikvm(1806): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    01-09 22:17:06.589: WARN/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(1031): setKernelCountSet(10044, 0) failed with errno -2
    01-09 22:17:07.899: INFO/Process(1806): Sending signal. PID: 1806 SIG: 9
    01-09 22:17:07.919: INFO/ActivityManager(1031): Process com.example.MapTest (pid 1806) has died.
    01-09 22:17:08.109: WARN/InputManagerService(1031): Window already focused,    ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@414b9608
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to run Google Android Maps v2 on emulator (see response from Android devs [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tyz491d96Ci)). You should use real device instead.

However, you can look for updates in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937) - looks like someone managed to create emulator which supports Google Android Maps v2

EDIT:
I can see some problem in your code:
You should extend `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, but not regular `Activity` class.

Also make sure you have added GooglePlayServices project (actually imported entire project) but not just a jar file. If you are using Eclipse, import the library project into your workspace. Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed the problem. Google has a very bad tutorial. First of all thank you Pavel Dudka for the big help.
i imported google play lib as module and then google play lib as jar then i also added onother jar file  android.suport.v4.jar were is can be found as the name is exmaple android\suppor\v4
After those modifications and with the recomentations the map did not work so i added the modified fragment bellow instead of using the one google provited and the map worked like a charm.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```