# How to show Google Map V2 on Android Emulator?

Tags: android

I tried so many steps which i acquired from googling to implement google map v2(version-2) on Android emulator .But i could not get output on emulator.Google map v1 is working fine.but i need google map v2..can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Maps V2 isn't meant to work on an emulator since it is bundled with the Google Play Services.

If you're still wondering how to make it work on the emulator, you might want to give this [blog post](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/2012/12/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/) and [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937) a read. As pointed out by CommonsWare, the tweaks listed in these article boil down to pirating software. If you're really thinking about developing on Android, you might wanna consider buying a device.

Comment: "Google Maps V2 won't work on an emulator without some tweaks." -- only if by "tweaks" you mean "pirating software".

Comment: ya..i already gone through the blog u said..it asked me to install two apk files(vending & gms) on emulator..i installed it ..while i'm executing google mapv2 from my own app,it asks me to update google play services..what should i have to do.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems so I prepared step by step tutorial to show how you can use google map android v2 on emulator(android 4.2.2) have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Answer (score 2):

I just run google map v2 on my emulator. It worked well.
I using emulator with taget Android 4.1.2-API Level 16.
I installed Google play, google play services, google services framework.

You can try.

This is my project.
https://github.com/kydinh/AndroidMapV2