# Unfortunately Google Maps API has stopped on emulator

Tags: android

I began in Android development and went to Google Maps with sample code from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code. I followed all the steps in this site with no change from my side, and when I run I see this message on the emulator: Unfortunately Google Maps API has stopped.

Here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapdemo"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.1.0">
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission >android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!-- End of copy. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/demo_title"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDYj6PVzqEyVw5ZItRp-PKrVEIb8woTdVc"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".BasicMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/basic_map"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/camera_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".CircleDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/circle_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".EventsDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/events_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".GroundOverlayDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/groundoverlay_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".LayersDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/layers_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationSourceDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/locationsource_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MarkerDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/marker_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".OptionsDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/options_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PolygonDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/polygon_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PolylineDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/polyline_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProgrammaticDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/programmatic_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".TileOverlayDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/tile_overlay_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".UiSettingsDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/uisettings_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".RawMapViewDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/raw_mapview_demo"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".RetainMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/retain_map"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MultiMapDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/multi_map_demo"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is the `main.java` file:

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.mapdemo.view.FeatureView;
import android.app.Activity;

public final class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static class DemoDetails {
        private final int titleId;
        private final int descriptionId;
        private final Class<? extends FragmentActivity> activityClass;
        public DemoDetails(
                int titleId, int descriptionId, Class<? extends FragmentActivity> >activityClass) {
            super();
            this.titleId = titleId;
            this.descriptionId = descriptionId;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
        }
    }


    private static class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DemoDetails> {
        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, DemoDetails[] demos) {
            super(context, R.layout.feature, R.id.title, demos);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            FeatureView featureView;
            if (convertView instanceof FeatureView) {
                featureView = (FeatureView) convertView;
            } else {
                featureView = new FeatureView(getContext());
            }

            DemoDetails demo = getItem(position);

            featureView.setTitleId(demo.titleId);
            featureView.setDescriptionId(demo.descriptionId);

            return featureView;
        }
    }


    private static final DemoDetails[] demos = {
        new DemoDetails(
            R.string.basic_map, R.string.basic_description, BasicMapActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.camera_demo, R.string.camera_description,
                    CameraDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.events_demo, R.string.events_description,
                    EventsDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.layers_demo, R.string.layers_description,
                    LayersDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(
                    R.string.locationsource_demo, R.string.locationsource_description,
                    LocationSourceDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.uisettings_demo, R.string.uisettings_description,
                    UiSettingsDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.groundoverlay_demo, >R.string.groundoverlay_description,
                    GroundOverlayDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.marker_demo, R.string.marker_description,
                    MarkerDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.polygon_demo, R.string.polygon_description,
                    PolygonDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.polyline_demo, R.string.polyline_description,
                    PolylineDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.circle_demo, R.string.circle_description,
                    CircleDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.tile_overlay_demo, R.string.tile_overlay_description,
                    TileOverlayDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.options_demo, R.string.options_description,
                    OptionsDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.multi_map_demo, R.string.multi_map_description,
                    MultiMapDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.retain_map, R.string.retain_map_description,
                    RetainMapActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.raw_mapview_demo, R.string.raw_mapview_description,
                    RawMapViewDemoActivity.class),
            new DemoDetails(R.string.programmatic_demo, R.string.programmatic_description,
                    ProgrammaticDemoActivity.class)
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, demos);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        DemoDetails demo = (DemoDetails) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, demo.activityClass));
    }
}
```

And here is the main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/no_demos"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the full logcat:

```
03-09 03:09:11.425: W/dalvikvm(2796): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/mapdemo/BasicMapActivity; (75)
03-09 03:09:11.425: W/dalvikvm(2796): Link of class 'Lcom/example/mapdemo/BasicMapActivity;' failed
03-09 03:09:11.455: E/dalvikvm(2796): Could not find class 'com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity', referenced from method com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.<clinit>
03-09 03:09:11.455: W/dalvikvm(2796): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 117 (Lcom/example/mapdemo/BasicMapActivity;) in Lcom/example/mapdemo/MainActivity;
03-09 03:09:11.455: D/dalvikvm(2796): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000d
03-09 03:09:11.485: W/dalvikvm(2796): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/mapdemo/MainActivity;
03-09 03:09:11.555: W/dalvikvm(2796): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/mapdemo/MainActivity;)
03-09 03:09:11.555: D/AndroidRuntime(2796): Shutting down VM
03-09 03:09:11.555: W/dalvikvm(2796): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     at com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:98)
03-09 03:09:11.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2796):     ... 15 more
03-09 03:09:15.014: I/Process(2796): Sending signal. PID: 2796 SIG: 9
```

I am using the emulator with API 17 Platform 4.2.2 Target Google APIs and device 5.1 "WVGA (480 * 800: mdpi).

How can I solve this problem?

Also, I was thinking to buy device [Samsung Galaxy Mini 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Mini_2) S6500 to run on it my applications instead of emulators. Would this device be suitable or not?

It has 512 MB RAM and Android OS, v2.3.6 ([Gingerbread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Gingerbread)), planned upgrade to v4.1.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We're happy to help with specific problems but this seems pretty general. Please try to narrow down the problem as closely as you can and then present to us the specific issues that are causing errors. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445093/how-to-show-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator) and many others on Google Maps V2 and the emulator, Google Maps API requires a real device to run. Any Gingerbread+ phone would work.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i am planning to buy Samsung Galaxy mini 2 S6500 with OS Android OS, v2.3.6 (Gingerbread), plnned upgrada to v4.1 will that work, i just want to make sure of that.

Comment: @AhmedBasiouny - yes, that phone would work fine (although it might be a little slow/too little RAM for terrain overlays, but basic maps should be fine).