# Android and the Google Map API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I still am not able to successfully launch the Google Map v2 on the emulator. I tried every single example and tutorial but still the same problem.

Now I get this problem: it display on the emulator screen that I need to update the Google Play Services but it is the latest update.

## Log cat

```
 04-13 05:32:50.979: E/Trace(680): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    04-13 05:32:51.223: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(680): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 1
    04-13 05:32:51.230: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(680): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 1
    04-13 05:32:51.250: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(680): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 1
    04-13 05:32:51.269: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(680): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 1
    04-13 05:32:51.280: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(680): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 1
    04-13 05:32:51.319: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(680): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 1
    04-13 05:32:51.650: D/gralloc_goldfish(680): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445093/how-to-show-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator

Comment: yes i ask these questions because i did not get any solution that make the application to work