# Crashes when showing map on real device, running on emulator shows google play service missing

Tags: android

when ever i run this app on emulator it shows google play service missing.But when i run same application on real device it unexpectedly stops the application making it to crash
here is code for my map

`

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/loc_finder"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
          <service android:name="jade.android.MicroRuntimeService" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.location_finder.Login_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.proximitymapv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ProximityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.activity.proximity"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
                </intent-filter>

        </activity>




        <activity android:name="com.example.location_finder.New_User_Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.location_finder.Welcome_Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.location_finder.Search_Friend_Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.location_finder.Search_Location_Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.location_finder.GPSLocatorActivity" >
        </activity>
          <activity android:name="chat.client.gui.MainActivity" />
          <activity android:name="chat.client.gui.ChatActivity" /> 
          <activity android:name="chat.client.gui.ChatClientActivity" /> 
          <activity android:name="chat.client.gui.ParticipantsActivity" /> 
       </application>


      <uses-permission
          android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.proximitymapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.proximitymapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDgah79JaIABl54K8V8HfB7UzopKVwtgzw"/> 

</manifest>
```

`

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

{

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


     // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available           

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);           


        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        // Opening the sharedPreferences object
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

        // Getting stored latitude if exists else return 0
        String lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat", "0");

        // Getting stored longitude if exists else return 0
        String lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng", "0");

        // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
        String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

        // If coordinates are stored earlier
        if(!lat.equals("0")){

            // Drawing circle on the map
            drawCircle(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));

            // Drawing marker on the map
            drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));

            // Moving CameraPosition to previously clicked position
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))));

            // Setting the zoom level in the map
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Float.parseFloat(zoom)));                


        }


        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Removes the existing marker from the Google Map
                googleMap.clear();      

                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(point);

                // Drawing circle on the map
                drawCircle(point);                  

                // This intent will call the activity ProximityActivity
                Intent proximityIntent = new Intent("in.wptrafficanalyzer.activity.proximity");                 

                // Creating a pending intent which will be invoked by LocationManager when the specified region is
                // entered or exited
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, proximityIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                  

                // Setting proximity alert 
                // The pending intent will be invoked when the device enters or exits the region 20 meters
                // away from the marked point
                // The -1 indicates that, the monitor will not be expired
                locationManager.addProximityAlert(point.latitude, point.longitude, 20, -1, pendingIntent);  

                /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                /** Storing the latitude of the current location to the shared preferences */
                editor.putString("lat", Double.toString(point.latitude));

                /** Storing the longitude of the current location to the shared preferences */
                editor.putString("lng", Double.toString(point.longitude));

                /** Storing the zoom level to the shared preferences */
                editor.putString("zoom", Float.toString(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));               

                /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
                editor.commit();                

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proximity Alert is added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    

            }
        });    

        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {              
            //@Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                Intent proximityIntent = new Intent("in.wptrafficanalyzer.activity.proximity");

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, proximityIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Removing the proximity alert                 
                locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);

                // Removing the marker and circle from the Google Map
                googleMap.clear();

                // Opening the editor object to delete data from sharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                // Clearing the editor
                editor.clear();

                // Committing the changes
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proximity Alert is removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });           
    }   
}   

private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);

    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

}


private void drawCircle(LatLng point){

    // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

    // Specifying the center of the circle
    circleOptions.center(point);

    // Radius of the circle
    circleOptions.radius(20);

    // Border color of the circle
    circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Fill color of the circle
    circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);

    // Border width of the circle
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);

    // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
    googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
05-04 22:36:22.820: D/SensorManager(29794): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c2ce28
05-04 22:36:22.870: D/dalvikvm(29794): GC_CONCURRENT freed 209K, 9% free 13173K/14407K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 17ms
05-04 22:36:22.875: D/AndroidRuntime(29794): Shutting down VM
05-04 22:36:22.875: W/dalvikvm(29794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e542a0)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.location_finder/in.wptrafficanalyzer.proximitymapv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.proximitymapv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-04 22:36:22.885: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services. (via Bazaar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show Google Map V2 on Android Emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445093/how-to-show-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator)

Comment: The emulator doesn't support Google Maps v2. As to why it crashes on a real device - please post the log from LogCat.

Comment: see i have added logcat value

Comment: if you read the log you can see what the problem is. line `55` in your `MainActivity` something is null

Comment: SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();//line 55 is there anythiong wrong in this..

Comment: is there any problem regarding use of map i mean i m using two different maps in my project one is version 1 and second is version 2 which i m getting isuue with

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already had fixed this issue.

But from the code side, you need to check whether fm is null before you tried to use it.

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```