# Android Google Maps V2 not working in Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have been trying for the last 2 hours now to get the map to work in the emulator on Mac. I have followed several suggestions on Stack such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445093/how-to-show-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator) I have tried over and over again, are these out of date?

I have done several new projects, fresh virtual devices, cleaned all the time and it's just not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: you will have to test it on a real device, try this work around https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527. but recommend to test it on real device

Comment: @Raghunandan hey I have followed this - but it says: "This app wont run unless you update Google Play Services" what should I do? Thanks for the link, easy to follow

Comment: scroll down the link and check the note you have to use rev 4 of google play services lib

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the reply! I have tried that, but the version that was in my lib folder in my workspace was version 4. Once I have replaced the file what should I do then?

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry, should I be going to Preferences > Properties -> Library and add it in? Because that is referencing a file in my SDK -> extras -> google

Comment: follow the link if it works fine else test it on a real device

Comment: Note that all of these suggestions for setting up an emulator involve software piracy. Google *has* announced that they are working on official emulator images that support Maps V2, but AFAIK they are not ready yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare well I saw this before https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#may_2013 in the newest release it says its compatible? It says "Android emulator support. (Issue 4627)"

Comment: @JoshBoothe: Like the others in that issue, I have not gotten Maps V2 to work on the API Level 17 emulator. Admittedly, I did not try all that hard, as I test maps on hardware, and I'll make a point of trying it again here this week sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you ask after installing apk files I have successfully run the google map version 2 on Android version 4.2.2 level 17 emulator. I have spend 2 days to find what is the problem.

make sure you have updated version of google api with latest updated version.
and google play service in extra folder of Android Sdk Manager.

Link To follow all step to start map v2 on emulator: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

```
steps:
1) delete your current AVD or Genymotion emulator
2) create new AVD or Genumotion emulator
    - Device: select Device any
    - Target: choose target as you want but make sure it should be  4.0 or greater
    - CPU: Intel or ARM
    - RAM, Heap, Internal storage, sd card: it should be lower according to your pc specification means if you have good RAM and process then go for the higher as you can.
```

you need to install

```
    three apk files on emulator
    1)  com.android.vending.apk
    2) com.google.android.gms.apk ( above both are given in the link)

    Note: Google play service apk (gms) version should be same as your
    google play service library mention in your code. Check google play
    service library version name and download the same version of apk file

    3) com.google.android.maps
```

**EDIT:**

if you have successfully install all these on your emulator without failure then you will definitely open google map on emulator.

**one more thing I would like to suggest you that version of google play service library that you refer in you project should be same as you install google play service apk file. It is not mandatory but some time you may face the same problem google play service version miss match error.**

I have found some link hope it will help you. Apk file download link:

For,

gms: http://uploaded.net/file/bnzl1si4

vending: http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=9390135922294521859

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, will it wor with API 17? Also, what were the links? They aren't formatting ;)

Comment: @JoshBoothe yes of-course!! I have successfully install in the same version on emulator.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot now. Do you have the links for setting up the emulator?

Comment: it is the same link suggest by me in answer as same as @Raghunandan told you in comment.

Comment: I have tried this with no success, the app just crashes now :/

Comment: have you install maps and google play service apk file in emulator? what error you get?

Comment: Erm, I didnt install them via the ADB, I just ticked google play services in extra and Google APIs, is there something else I need? I have installed the 2 files vending and gms through ADB

Comment: yes you should install google play service and map apk file at least in your emulator. Google play service is needed to open your google map in version 2 and by using map you can check even by default map is working properly or not in emulator.

Comment: okay first try to reinstall maps,gms and vending apk file in your emulator. maps can download from this link: http://www.apk4.net/applications/travel-local/google-maps-6-14-3-apk/.

Comment: check my edited answer in steps and try to install 3 files maps,gms,vending apk. hope it will help you.