# How to download Google Play Services in an Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use Google Play Services API in my application, but when I open the emulator to test my application it sends me a message that says "Google Play Services must be downloaded". I know that occurs because I coded this test in my `MainActivity` in the method `onResume()`.
I want to know how I can install Google Play Services in my emulator, because soon I will need to test my maps.

Comment: Just use the latest `AVD image` from Google which has `Google play serveices` embedded. Check for the update from the `SDK manager`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Check out [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) which says:

> To develop an app using the [Google Play services APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html), you need to set up your project with the Google Play services SDK.
>
> If you haven't installed the Google Play services SDK yet, go get it now by following the guide to [Adding SDK Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html).
>
> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
>
> - A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
> - The Android emulator with an [AVD](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Comment: There has been updates, developer site quoted: "The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher."

Comment: I tried using the Android API (version 4.3) and it didn't work, so the key is to use the Google API (version 4.3). Since they were the same version number, I didn't realize why it wasn't running at first.

Comment: I am using Google APIS ver. 22  with Intel x86_64.  Does not work.

Comment: The important thing here is what @Skitterm wrote. The AVD must have Google APIs as a target. Interestingly selecting a lower API target than 23 (Marshmallow) results in the device trying to update the Google Play services which always fails for me.

Comment: Has anyone ever gotten this to work? It seems that using an Android image with Google API does not work with Google Play.

Answer (score 81):

For **api 21+** you can use system image with Google Play as I describe below.

For **api 19+** (Android 4.4 Kitkat) you can use system image x86 with Google Api (I was able to use it).

For **api 17+** (Android 4.2.2) you can TRY to use system image ARM with Google Api (It didn't work for me).

I was able to install Google Play and Google Services as separate apks to pure system image api 16 and 17, but they don't really work after that (services crush and play not opens). So seems like it is not possible to make them work on pure AVD image because they should be installed with root access. The same for updating Google Services on AVD system image with Google API preinstalled - can't update because of incompatible certificates, can't uninstall even using adb because don't have access.

---

### How to setup AVD system image with Google Play

Now even better solution exist: using AVD image with build-in Google Play Services. It will enable you to use Google Services including Google Play. Also you will be able update it without re-creating AVD image.

Open AVD manager and choose create new device. You should use device definition with play store icon.

[image: 1]

Then choose system image for it. You should choose one with **Google Play** and **NOT** with Google API.

[image: 2]

Then launch new device.

[image: 3]

You can update Play Services as shown on screenshot, or manually in app itself, just like a real device.

[image: 4]

**Update 2022;** but even with above, you cannot use the Emulator to test Google Play Billing:

> - You must install your application on a real device to test Google Play Billing,
> - Or, ask Google for "closed testing" permission.
>
> see [How to test In-app Billing on an emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26100032/8740349)

Comment: Which android studio version should one use to have this option?

Comment: @ronenmiller I am using last stable version, now it's 2.3.3.
But it should not depend on Android Studio version. It depends on Android System Image version, and maybe on Android Virtual Device Manager's version, but I'm not sure about last. I just always update everything to last stable version.

Comment: Isn't available on 3.1.3

Comment: @Emaborsa did you chose image with Google Play or Google API? I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4 now and everything works fine.

Comment: @B-GangsteR Yes I did

Answer (score 7):

I came across another solution to use the Google play services on an emulator.  The guys at http://www.genymotion.com/ provide very fast emulators on which you can install Google play services.  They just need you to sign up to begin downloading and you need Virtual box installed.  At the moment they cater for Android 16 and 17 but more are on the way.

Comment: They used to until Google told them to stop providing an infinitely better service than Google ever has, and forced them to rip out the Play Store from their images.

Comment: Said Oh!, went to create a new emulator for testing tablets on my existing genymotion app, the read your comment and hated people I don't know for a second.

Comment: genymotion was a great emulator but it seems it does not work with maps now :(

Answer (score 3):

In the current version (Android Studio 0.5.2) there is now a device type for "Google APIs x86 (Google Inc.) - API Level 19".

Answer (score 3):

The key is to select the target of your emulator to, for example: *Google APIs (ver 18)*.
If you select, for example, just *Jellybean 18* (without API) you will not be able to test apps that require Google services such as map.
Keep in mind that you must first download the Google API of your favorite version with the Android SDK Manager.

This is a good practice and it is far better than juggling with most workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to develop google MAP API V2 application recently and tried to run it through emulator but I everytime it showed me error "Google Play Servcies is not installed in this phone".
From my perpective even I think google MAP API V2 doesn't work on emulator.

Solution

Then I tried to run the same example on my Sony Experia you and again it showed me same error.
Then I installed google play services on my mobile and amazingly it started working..:)))

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by

- Installing the Google Play Services through the Android SDK Manager
- Using a Galaxy Nexus Device (4.65", 720 x 1280: xhdpi)
- Targeting the Android 4.2.2 Google API Level 17

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://university.xamarin.com/resources/working-with-android-emulators .
Scroll down to the "Installing Google Play Services" section.  Step by step walk through there.

Directly plagarized from xamarin here so I don't get dinged for linking and not including solution.  Posting this as I found the hit in stack before I found the solution that worked across the board on the xamarin page.

1. Start the Xamarin Android Player and run one of the supplied images, the following assumes you have started the KitKat Nexus 4 image.
   Download the proper Google Play Services .zip file from www.teamandroid.com/gapps/ . Make sure to download the image appropriate for your version of Android.
2. Drag the .zip file onto the running emulator and drop it to install the component, here we show it on Mac OS X, but the same mechanism is used in Windows. You will get a prompt to install the package onto the emulator which indicates the image will be restarted
3. Once it restarts, you will get a notification that installation is completed, and the image will now have Google Maps, Google+ and support for the Google Play store. Note that some things do not work correctly and you may get a few errors from some of the services, but you can safely dismiss these and continue the instructions.
4. Next, you will need to associate a Google account so that you can update the services using the Google Play store. It should prompt you for this, but if it does not, you can go into the Google Settings and add a new account.
   Once you've added the account, you can then update the Google apps by opening the Google Play store application and going into settings from the side bar menu.
5. Select Settings and then scroll down to the Build Version number information and double-tap on it until it tells you it is either up-to-date, or that it will download and install a new version.
6. Power off the device (press and hold the power button in the toolbar on the right) and restart it. Once it restarts, it should indicate that it needs to update the Google Play services, tapping the notification will open the Google Play Store and install the latest version

Now you can run applications that depend on Google Maps in the Xamarin Android Player.

Answer (score 0):

To the latest setup and information if you have installed the Android Studio (i.e. 1.5) and trying to target SDK 4.0 then you may not be able to locate and setup the and AVD Emulator with SDK-vX.XX (with Google API's).

See following steps in order to download the required library and start with that.
[AVD Emulator setup -setting up Emulator for SDK4.0 with GoogleAPI so Map application can work- In Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/286pS.png)

But unfortunately above method did not work well on my side. And was not able to created Emulator with API Level 17 (SDK 4.2). So I followed this post that worked on my side well. The reason seems that the Android Studio Emulator creation window has limited options/features.

[Google Play Services in emulator, implementing Google Plus login button etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I got here because I had a similar problem as everyone above. I solved it by just reading a little closer!

I hadn't noticed there were 2 possible system Images I could choose from, one that contained Google APIs and one that didn't (on my laptop the menu was too small for me to read the (with Google APIs) text appended.

It's a stupid thing to miss, but someone else might have a small screen like I did, and miss this :D

Answer (score 0):

If your emulator x86 this method works your me.

Download and install http://opengapps.org/app/opengapps-app-v16.apk. And select nano pack

More info http://opengapps.org/app/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am seeing 'connection to server failed errror'