# How to implement google map in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a MainActivity which has an ActionBar with two tab, the first tab is to show the sensor data value and the second tab I want to show the Map.
But I have a problem to implement the map in the fragment on the second tab

The MainActivity is shown as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private static final String DATA_FRAGMENT_BAR = "Data";
private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_BAR = "Map";

private DataCollection mDataCollection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Config.mContext = this;
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME| ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab dataTab = actionBar.newTab().setText(DATA_FRAGMENT_BAR);
    ActionBar.Tab mapTab = actionBar.newTab().setText(MAP_FRAGMENT_BAR);
    Fragment dataFragment = new FragmentData();
    Fragment mapFragment = new FragmentMap();

    dataTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(dataFragment));
    mapTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mapFragment));

    actionBar.addTab(dataTab);
    actionBar.addTab(mapTab);
    mDataCollection = DataCollection.getInstance();
}
....
}
```

The TabsListener is shown as below
    public class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {
    private Fragment fragment;

```
public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment)
{
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ft.remove(fragment);
}
}
```

The the map fragment class is shown as below:

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment
{

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    //map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    //map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(50.167003,19.383262)));


    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try 
    {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } 
    catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory()
{
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

I set a break point in the FragmentMap class at the line "mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" the savedInstanceState is null and the program will crash after line.

Can someone help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google released the Map API Version 2. This gives you a MapFragment and a SupportMapFragment. This allows you to add a Map without extending MapActivity.

[Google Maps v2 In fragment cashes when clicked twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127443/google-maps-v2-in-fragment-cashes-when-clicked-twice)

Comment: I have add the TabsListener class on the question. My problem is if I used the MapFragment, the TabsListener will not work. I have two tabs, one of the tabs is to show the sensors value, so I used Fragment

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear in the documentation, but the `MapView.onCreate()` method should be called in the **`Fragment.onActivityCreated()`**, not in `Fragment.onCreate()`

Also, `MapView.getMap()` can return null, don't forget to check with that.

And you should call `super.onResume()` before `mapView.onResume()`