# Inflate Exception on clicking on map fragment twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a menu item that displays the map when you click on it. When I click on this menu item twice, it gives me the following error:

```
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318): Process: com.example.makemyday, PID: 4318
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at com.example.makemyday.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:24)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #21: Duplicate id 0x7f050028, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-31 12:32:13.569: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):     ... 20 more
```

Here is my code for MapFragment:

```
package com.example.makemyday;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment  implements OnItemSelectedListener{

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       { 
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);
         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         DateTimeFragment datetime=new DateTimeFragment();
         ft.add(R.id.datetime_container_map, datetime);
         SupportMapFragment mapFragment=null;
         if(mapFragment==null)
             mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
         ft.commit();

         AutoCompleteTextView location= (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.location_map);
         location.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_layout));

         Spinner category=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.category_query_map);
         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCategory = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.array.category_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
         adapterCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         category.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
         category.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

         return v;
       }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
}
```

Here is my code for the layout of map fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:background="@color/translucent_grey"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_location"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/datetime_container_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.00" />
     <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/category_query_map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Why is there no exception when I create the map fragment for the first time, but an exception if i create it the second time?

Comment: Go to this question:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127443/google-maps-v2-in-fragment-cashes-when-clicked-twice?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127443/google-maps-v2-in-fragment-cashes-when-clicked-twice?rq=1)

Comment: can you also post the code where you have written menu onclick

Comment: what is your min sdk in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out as below : Use the `getMap()` to load the map.

```
  if(mapFragment==null)
         mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment).getMap();
```

Comment: how can you do getMap for a SupportMapFragment(). Isn't it going to be a type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

For instance of FragmentManager use below.

```
mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
```

Comment: you cannot use getSupportFragmentManager inside a Fragment. It can only be used inside a class that extends FragmentActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

to

```
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

inside fragment use this

```
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Also

```
private GoogleMap map;
....
map = ((SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: SUpportMapFragment can only be used inside a class that extends FragmentActivity