# App is crashing on back pressed when use map inside fragment in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

i have used navigation drawer in actionbar activity now i used multiple fragment in same activity but problem is when i first time load mapfragment it is display perfectly but when i press backbutton my app is crashing it is display illegal argument exception.

> Mapfragment.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.compass.DirectionsJSONParser;
import com.compass.GPSTracker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    GoogleMap googlemap;
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        gps=new GPSTracker(getActivity());
        googlemap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapviews)).getMap();  
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // current location
        double currentlat=gps.getLatitude();
        double currentlon=gps.getLongitude();

        // destination location
        //double destlat=23.048854;
        //double destlon=72.516059;

        double destlat=22.9833;
        double destlon=72.5000;

        final LatLng currentpoint = new LatLng(currentlat,currentlon);
        final LatLng destinationpoint = new LatLng(destlat,destlon);

        // fro add marker on map
        googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(new LatLng(currentlat, currentlon))
                 .title("Current Location")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_source)));

        googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(237.0f));
        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentpoint));

        googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(destlat, destlon))
        .title("WebOffice")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_destination)));

        /*
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(currentpoint, destinationpoint);              
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);
        */

    }
```

> fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapviews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> Logcat

```
 12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701): Process: com.weboffice, PID: 9701
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at com.weboffice.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:45)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f0b005c, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    12-09 11:48:05.165: E/AndroidRuntime(9701):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: using fragment inside a fragment.

Comment: You need to remove Fragment when you press back.. in `onDestroyView(....)`

Comment: one issue is coming when i open second time it will crash again and display same error

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127443/google-maps-v2-in-fragment-cashes-when-clicked-twice?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use this code

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {       
    super.onDestroyView();

    try {
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and mark this ans up if this helps

Comment: Hey one issue is coming when i open second time it will crash

Comment: when its happening..?? when u resume ur app after onpause..??

Comment: no on sliding navigation i have 4 item office,map,compass,webpage first time if i press map than it will display but when if i press second time map than it will crash

Comment: dats easy man just diable the click on that mapbutton once its clicked and enable it quickly once the user press any button other than map... :)

Comment: but that is not right solution check this pastie what error is coming http://pastie.org/9769713

Comment: check my other ans..tell me if u got me... :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring de SupportMapFragment in layout, do it programatically and be sure you use getChildFragmentMananger instead of the classic getFragmentManager() to create the fragment.

```
mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
         getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_root, mMapFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Keep this SupportMapFragment mMapFragment as you will need it to retrieve the GoogleMap object:

```
 GoogleMap map = mMapFragment.getMap();
```

Comment: but if i use this than it will give 12-09 18:23:40.805: E/AndroidRuntime(15529): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null

Comment: Yes, you need to wait for a run before the map gets initialised. I use a delay handler to grab a reference to the map after 10 milliseconds, alternatively use the lifecycle to your advantage. i.e. commit the fragment in onCreate and then grab a reference to the map in onResume. –

Answer (score 0):

also work like this

```
  @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        try{
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapviews));
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
          }catch(Exception e){
          }

        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```