# NullPointerException in fragment's onCreateView only on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-emulator, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in the `onCreateView` method of my fragment but what is strange is that this only occurrs on the emulator. On the device the app runs fine.

If I set a breakpoint for NullPointerException and debug in eclipse it stops at this line:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapTrackButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.track_user_button);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // This line
        // More code

    }
```

Comment: You should inspect what `getMap()` returns. It's probably returning something `null` ;)

Comment: I think there may be some problem in R.id.map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google maps is not available on emulator.

To fix error do this:

```
if (map != NULL) {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To be more specific, the emulator does not support the Google Play services which has the Google Maps API unless it is running 4.2.2 or higher. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14536645/634474

Comment: But my emulator is running 4.4.2?

Comment: Are you using 'Android 4.2.2 - API Level 19' or 'Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 19'? From dymmeh link seems that you need to use 'Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 19'.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it turned out that I din't use the Google APIs on the emulator...