# Google Play Services not working on Android emulator API Level 11

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm developing an app that uses Google Maps, but everytime I navigate to Map Activity, throws this message: `This app won't run without Google PLay services, which are missing from your phone`. I'm using Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 11. It should work becauses it is the system image with Google Play services.

I'm using Android Studio and using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:+` dependencies.
Can anybody tell me if there is something I'm missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem: I created a new Android Virtual Device but not with Google APIs, but Android API 11.

I had to install manually Google Play Services and Google Play Store but not using Google APIs through the command prompt.

This was useful for me:

[Configuring Android Emulator to Run Google Map v2](http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/)

And this:

[Android Google Maps API V2 Run On Emulator and Run On API Level 10 or 9 or 8 or Android 2 3 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUsBOZ7-qBE)

Answer (score 1):

The device needs to have Google Play Services installed.

You can check if the phone/device/emulator has it installed by using this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)

It seems like Google Play services is not supported by the emulator:
[How to download Google Play Services in an Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-a-android-emulator)

Comment: Thank you, your second link gave a clue, I solved my problem, thank you!! @Heinrisch