# Can't get google maps to work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

My friends and I are working on creating a phone application which involves the use of google maps, so we can place markers that will show information once selected. The problem we encounter is that we are unable to get the google maps plug-in to work.

We have done the following:
 - Added: Android support repository, Google play services, Google repository.
 - The following was added to our gradle module.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wilmar.rentacube"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

We have also Synced the project with the gradle files. However when we try to run it in our emulator it says that we need to update google play services.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you in advance.:)

The code that is in our google maps activity as requested:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.example.wilmar.rentacube.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

NOTE!: This code is automatically generated by Android Studio!

Comment: have created the api key for google maps ?

Comment: Yes this has been created

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Check out : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: We are using the google maps activity, handed to us by android studio

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator

If possible, I suggest you test on a physical device instead.

Answer (score 0):

> it says that we need to update google play services

Well, the Google Maps are the part of Google Play Services which should be installed on your device to run this application. If demo app says that you need to update the Play Services, it means that either Google Play Services aren't installed on the device or their version is less than required by the application. E.g. Play Services installed on the device have the version of 6.5.11, app requires 7.0 - you get update dialog on the start.
There is only one solution. Open Google Play Market, find Google Play Services and update them to the latest release.