# Google play services & google play games app on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I recently updated the **android google sdk** with the latest version of `google play services library (7.5)`.

Since the update I cannot run my app on emulator : when I click sign in button a pop up appears saying that I need to install the l**atest version of google play games app**.

Of course I'm using the `latest google apis` for the emulator image. What happens? Did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: Your emulator itself needs Google Play Services. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator).

Comment: @Andy I already did everything is listed in that answer. As you can see I'm using Google APIs v19 rev. 14 (latest) on a 4.4.2 emulator. Anyway before the latest play services update everything was ok, now I'm stuck on this. I starting to think that is a bug introduced by Google.

Comment: What you've shown is what your app is built on, not what it's running on. In the actual emulator, you need to install Google Play Services. Download the apk for Google Play Services and the Google Play store and install them into your emulator via ADB. Either that or test with a physical device, which I suggest as it'll probably be the better testing platform.

Comment: @Andy I don't think I have to install any apk via adb on the emulator. As from google documentation: _To use these APIs in the Android emulator, you must also install the the Google APIs system image from the latest Android X.X directory in the SDK Manager_. And this is what I did but is not working, I'm wondering where it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns that now google play services is linked to google play games app. It seems that if you don't have the app installed you cannot run the game that uses google play services. The emulator of course come without the games app I have to manually install the apk and now it works again. :-o

[image]

Comment: How do you install the Google Play Games app on the emulator?

Comment: I have downloaded the play games apk from [here](http://www.apk4fun.com/apk/1461/) then push it into the emulator: -adb install play_games.apk.  Note: I don't think it's the official way but at least I can use the emulator with google play services.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more 'official' place from which to download the apk?