# Access Not Configured for google calendar in android

Tags: android

I found an error Access Not Configured for google calendar. I follow all the steps which are described in developers console and also generate a client ID. When I run the code on emulator I get the error Install Google Play Services. When I click on install it dont allow me to install. And when I run code in my mobile it will give me the error Google Calendar API is not enabled for your project. Although I have already enabled it. And my code is same as https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android Please tell me how can I solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code in real device.
As Google Play store is not available in emulator.

I you want to run in emulator then go through this

[1. Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator)

[2. Google Play Services Missing in Emulator](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwiv2Y3C3eLGAhWGco4KHXNlCKg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22141043%2Fgoogle-play-services-missing-in-emulator-android-4-4-2&ei=wECpVa_5BobluQTzyqHACg&usg=AFQjCNEeLrlwPmpAsEB6-ECTQQjGxb5u3w&sig2=CJ26D8fk1CaeDZunQt7PbQ&bvm=bv.97949915,bs.1,d.c2E)

These have given the answer to install Google Play Service and then after you can easily run on emulator.