# How to install Google Play Service on the emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Would anyone know how to install Google Play Service on the emulator in Android Studio? I'm following the tutorial on how Google Cloud Messaging works. I copied the example and was trying to run it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work because it says Google play service is missing from your phone which means the emulator.
I'm using the latest version of Google API which is 23.

Comment: why not try gennymotion emulators, i feel they are better than stock emulators it still needs g play services installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download Google Play Services in an Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator)

Answer (score -1):

Best option is create the Virtual Device:

1. Open the Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Create a New device
3. Enter an AVD name
4. Set the target to Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 23 or above.

Save your Virtual device and start it...

Your code will run on emulator no need of Google Play Service.

Comment: I did that one too. It's asking me to update google play service. I tried to click the Update button but it's not updating at all.