# How to fixed if it won't run unless I update google play service in android studio

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

How to fix this problem, I tried many way to fix it. But it's still not working. I already installed google play service at SDK manager.

[image]

Comment: can not work, it will stop running

Comment: What version of Google Play Services is your device running? You can check the version on the Settings/Apps menu of your phone/tablet

Comment: i use virtual device in android studio, how to do that

Comment: Probably this post can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [updating Google play services in Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476182/updating-google-play-services-in-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle > use this

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'`

instead of this

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`

basically just change 8 to 4

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle (Module:app) I just changed

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
```

I tried initially changing to 11.0.0 but experienced the same problem with 11.0.0. so just tried with 10.0.0 and don't have any problems.