# Android Studio Emulator: Authentication failed. Timeout while trying to contact the server

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to learn Android development & doing it the first time to do some hands-on to develop my ideas. I want to load the google map with the current location on the emulator.

Referred SE Questions: [Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent)

Initially, I faced the problem ["won't run unless I update google play service in android studio"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730327/how-to-fixed-if-it-wont-run-unless-i-update-google-play-service-in-android-stud)

The problem got resolved after changing:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0+
```

I also corrected API_KEY by generating the API_KEY from the link given in code file. Now I am not getting that error but still not able to load the map on the emulator. These seem to be connection issue & I added the permission in manifest files as well. But the problem still persists. Kindly guide me & provide your valuable suggestions.

> google_maps_api.xml

```
<resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

    https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=6C:42:DD:0A:5D:D3:E4:5E:79:C9:04:81:3A:7A:70:17:25:37:97:96%3Bcom.example.kapilj3.meetmeapp

    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
    6C:42:DD:0A:5D:D3:E4:5E:79:C9:04:81:3A:7A:70:17:25:37:97:96;com.example.kapilj3.meetmeapp

    Alternatively, follow the directions here:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIza_MY_ACTUAL_KEY</string>
</resources>
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Is your MapActivity opening, and show you a white(not loaded) map ?

Comment: Yes correct. It is white screen with google at bottom

Comment: I had the same issue, and everything was set correctly..Later I found out that the problem was the API_KEY I used...on google console, click your api and use (Android api_key) the one autogenerated by them :) Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
   <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

add this code to your application manifiest

Comment: Do I need to replace "google_maps_key" with API_KEY ?

Comment: ya in value you have to put your map API KEY

Comment: Still, timeout is coming, will it use the source of the internet as my PC? I am checking it on Emulator, not on mobile. Will it work on the emulator as well?

Comment: ya connecting to MAPS need internet and use physical device for testing