# java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed:

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using `Emulator 7.1.1(Google Apis)`.
Full exception is

```
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 309

 java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: 12291
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bi.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:834)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:20825)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:881)
```

The code is working fine on `samsung galaxy J5` but not working on `emulator`. I have searched on google & my 2 hours wasted on this error & still not able to find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.katariya.pomoc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: install google play services in the emulator

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Try to install google play service in your emulator from here : [How to download Google Play Services in an Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator)

Answer (score 4):

I got it!

I went into the settings of the emulator itself and changed **OpenGL ES render** from **Autodetect based on host (default)** to **Desktop native OpenGL**. After that my app began working perfectly. Here is a screenshot for clarity, hope this helps somebody in the future!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new Emulator one can choose some options in Emulated performance. It may be *Automatic*, *Hardware GLES* or *Software GLES*. In my case ***Software GLES 2.0*** did the magic. The maps are working a little bit slower but fast enough to have patience to try my app out.

Here's the picture of place where to choose Emulation for Graphics
[image]