# Firebase error : Error (auth/network-request-failed

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I try to build an eCommerce app with Expo and react native but I face a network error, the google service is active on the device (simulator for android and real iPhone for IOS) and I'm connected to my Google account.

I also try to prevent the page to reload but nothing changed. After some research, all I see is I'm not the only one to face this error I don't find any valuable answer so I'm ending up here.

here my code:

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false);

  const handleCreateAccount = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authentification, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log(userCredential);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };

  const handleSignIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log("Signed in!");
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Alert.alert(error.message);
      });
  };

      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flex: 1,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <BlurView intensity={100}>
          <View style={styles.login}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: profilePicture }}
              style={styles.profilePicture}
            />
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, fontWeight: "400", color: "white" }}>
              email
            </Text>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="your@email.com"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              textContentType="emailAddress"
            />
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, fontWeight: "400", color: "white" }}>
              mot de passe
            </Text>
            <TextInput
              onChange={(text) => setPassword(text)}
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="your password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={handleSignIn}
              title="Connexion"
              buttonStyle={{
                width: 250,
                height: 40,
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: "#00CFEB90",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                marginVertical: 10,
                borderColor: "#fff",
                borderWidth: 2,
              }}
              type="outline"
              titleStyle={{ color: "white", fontSize: 17 }}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={handleCreateAccount}
              title="Créer un compte"
              buttonStyle={{
                width: 250,
                height: 40,
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: "#6792F090",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                marginVertical: 10,
                borderColor: "#fff",
                borderWidth: 2,
              }}
              type="outline"
              titleStyle={{ color: "white", fontSize: 17 }}
            />
          </View>
        </BlurView>
      </ScrollView>
```

So I need help.

Comment: I have the same problem with the web version, however, only on iOS devices. It works with other devices.

Comment: i think is the code for the form/text input cause i try the same function in another project with a different type of form and it's work on android simulator and the Iphone.

Answer (score 12):

**In case it helps someone.**
I had the same issue and lost many hours investigating.
It turned out that in my case, it was simply a DNS issue in the firebase layer.
`localhost` in the URL of the emulator was not resolved.
I replaced it with `127.0.0.1` and it is working fine.

Comment: Could you share where to get this info? I have the same error. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours. This fixed my situation running on MacOS

Answer (score 5):

The `auth/network-request-failed` error can be especially misleading as it seems to arise for a bunch of different reasons. I've seen it for any of the following:

1. **Wrong Version of the SDK** - To use auth on native devices, you need to use the native SDK, *not* the JavaScript SDK. Some other Firebase features may work via the JS SDK, but auth won't as it has extra security layers. Make sure you're using the correct version.
2. **Emulator Issues** - Your emulator can't access the internet or has stale DNS or an incorrect system time. Check and make sure your device has internet access, the clock on the device is set correctly, and that the DNS for your project resolves. For DNS you can try switching to Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) or Cloudflare's (1.1.1.1) and see if either of those help.
3. **No Google Play Services** - On Android, auth requires Google Play services be installed on the device emulator. [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-an-android-emulator/46246782#46246782).
4. **Incorrect Firebase Setup** - Make sure you've followed every item in the Getting Started instructions from both [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/setup-native-firebase/#bare-workflow-setup) and [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/#installation), in particular the credentials portions and making sure that the package names match on Android and Bundle IDs match on iOS.

If none of the above work, provide the full error your getting (check both the React errors and the device-level error logs).

Comment: this is driving me batty, I've checked everything 10 times :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72042995/createuserwithemailandpassword-creates-account-that-cant-be-seen-in-the-console

Answer (score 2):

This helped for error: `auth/network-request-failed` whilst using the iOS Simulator.

If you followed the documentation and implemented emulation for FirebaseAuth in debug mode. https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/

Setup the emulator then run:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

I should work after that and you can manage users at http://localhost:4000/auth.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on an ios simulator and the solution for me was to flash the dns on my mac by running
`sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Hope this helps someone