# Unable to login into google account in the Android emulator Mac Pro M1 Apple chip

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Currently, I am using Android Studio Dolphin on Mac book M1 Pro with an Apple chip. I successfully created an emulator with the below details. When I try to login into my google account/play store I am getting this error.

Currently, I can see due to this issue google services are not working in the emulator and for this reason, I am unable to generate the FCM token.

**FCM ERROR**

```
p                 E  Failed to get FIS auth token
                                                                                                java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(GmsRpc.java:260)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.startRpc(GmsRpc.java:222)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.getToken(GmsRpc.java:180)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$blockingGetToken$10$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:605)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.start(Unknown Source:6)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(RequestDeduplicator.java:67)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:601)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.SyncTask.maybeRefreshToken(SyncTask.java:121)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.messaging.SyncTask.run(SyncTask.java:91)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
                                                                                                Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:208)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:530)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:385)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2$com-google-firebase-installations-FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:374)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

2022-10-14 12:15:15.689   212-212   Layer                   pid-212                              E  [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{398d90f token=Token{4dd0e6e ActivityRecord{

**Google account error**

**[image: Emulator google account error]**

**Emulator details**
[image]

Comment: Try this thread-https://stackoverflow.com/a/46246782/18362930

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb Already tried it's not working