# Google Maps on Android blank space

Tags: android, google-maps

i some strange trouble with GoogleMaps on Android(api10), i think i got every i need to show map on my activity screen but it appear blank(gray space with grid and zoom buttons). Heres my AndroidManifest, layout file and source of activity.

[update]i make another project just for map

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pl.example.mapa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />   

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="pl.example.mapa.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyATooww6ZGs80CF_2Zyjc3OMj9igbFNu9k" />
</application>
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

mainActivity source

```
package pl.example.mapa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();
}
}
```

i cane add logs track due i cant run it on emulator

i bet its some little think i miss but after all search in this moment i have no idea whot is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an API Key to your Manifest file.

1) Obtain your API Key (Good instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start))

2) Add the following line to your Manifest file right before the  end tag.

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

Comment: i found my mistake, i choose google map api v2 not for android :( better late then never

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Maps v1, I had this issue as well. The new API (v2), requires the API key to be stored in the android manifest and uses a different library. I found [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) tutorial very useful when moving from v1 to v2.

Comment: Mr Vogel got gr8 android tutorial, but that1 is reason why im lost

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are mixing both API's of Google Maps services. Mostly you are using API v1 but this permissions is of API v2:

```
<permission
android:name="pl.mariusz.georeminder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="pl.mariusz.georeminder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

and might be the one that causing you problems.

I on the other hand would suggest you to move to API v2, as API v1 soon will be deprecated (if it isn't already), here is a blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Map API V2 into your application:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: @Mariusz, would you mind to update your question with current code, result and stack trace... so we will have more information then just: "i still get blank space..."