# Google maps show only a brown screen and zoom

Tags: java, android

I want to display google maps app in my android application:

I did the steps as mentioned in android developer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

However it display for me in my app , a brown screen with zoom (plus and minus buttons) without the map itself (it doesnt show me any error)

I created this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="66496.79"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="1"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <permission
    android:name="com.example.sal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name=".FriendPickerApplication">



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sal.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


              </activity>

         <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" android:label="Profile page"></activity>

        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="zzzz"/>


        <activity android:name="SaleMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="GroupMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="DeliverMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="PickFriendsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="TabMainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="itemSaleActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="FreindsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ExitActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="OneTimeDetailesScreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="UpdateMapActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="DashBoardActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest
```

>

Comment: what's your app's package name? is it `com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps`?

Comment: hi, i changes it to my package name, however it still the same issue...

Comment: have u checked your device's date/time? is it correct? I know it sounds weird but I've met the issue before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615759/blank-googlemap-on-a-real-android-2-3-device-with-google-api-lv-17/15630541?noredirect=1#15630541

Comment: yes, the device time and date is correct

Comment: can I know what's is your package name? could u post the updated manifest file to the question? thx

Comment: i changes it, however it still show blank

Comment: hi, i uploaded a new version of my manifest file, my project name is: com.example.sal

Comment: nothing showed via logcat?

Comment: maybe its because i  didnt choose "google API" as the build traget? nothing shows me like this on eclipse ,only "ANDROID 4.2.2"

Comment: Ahh, that's the problem, you need to choose Google API in your project settings. If you can't find it, launch SDK Manager to install it.

Comment: hi, iallready installed the google play sdk from sdk manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

to

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.sal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

I'm not sure if this will help but this is layout code I used last project
(note different fragment class)

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:mapType="normal"
            map:cameraTargetLat="@string/default_map_lat"
            map:cameraTargetLng="@string/default_map_lng"
            map:cameraZoom="8">
</fragment>
```

Comment: thanks alot, i will try it, also, do i need to change this line? :      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

Comment: @AdirRahamim no, you don't need to. please make sure to change the MAPS_RECEIVE 's package name to your own package name, clearly that @Corey not mean to change the package name to `example.sal` but your own package name.

Comment: this line <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"    android:targetSdkVersion="10" /> also seems a little odd.  try changing it to <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />