# Android - google map is showing blank screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

The Google map API V2 shows blank screen even I use the mapdemo project in Google play service sample

- I reinstall google play service SDK.
- I changed the API key
- I changed the debug.keystore and re-generate the sha1 fingerprint

nothing changed...

and `mMap` is always turning out to be null ?

```
if (mMap == null) { 
// Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment. 
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) .getMap(); 
// Check if we were successful in obtaining the map. 
if (mMap != null) { 
setUpMap(); 
}
```

Comment: Always show the code you have tried along with the question. Secondly have allowed the internet permissions in you Manifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes i allow the internet
 if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }

mMap is always null any reason?

Comment: Follow the link carefully, will surely work https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Comment: plz  put your xml file,?

Comment: @jibran i'm did those steps

Comment: @NesreenMansour is it something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636254/763459 I have encountered similar issues and solved by updating the device's time to the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I find that the device operating system just can handle map view not the map fragment.

Answer (score 1):

This problem (Blank map with zoom control) is usually derived from the fact that you didn't referenced `google-play-services` library correctly, or haven't configured the API in the console the right way.

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps API V2 in your application:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Follow the first 3 steps for correct `google-play-services` library integration.

Or check this post for the right configuration in the API console:

[Google Maps API V2 key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: please show more of your code: the manifest file, xml layout file and your map class.

Comment: i use the sample project in Desktop\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps
i didn't change anything except the api key

Comment: If you used the sample project then my guess would be that you are not configuring your API Console correctly. try to go over the second guide I posted.

Comment: no i created new api key with package name and debug.keystore

Comment: @NesreenMansour, as the result you are receiving is not the desired result, the conclusion is that you are doing something wrong. take a look at the steps of both guide and make sure you are making all of them right.

Comment: Emil i used your blog to create my first app and it really helps me i can't deny but i created an app it works very well but once the map disappeared i changed the api key and debug.keystore file but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

is your map showing zoom in-out signs?

**Edit:**
 try out like this.. i also had the same problem as yours.. and happened to solve it as below

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
```

Comment: i dont know why i cant directly post a comment just below your question.. sorry that i had to ask the question in answering section then

Comment: not this way mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) .getMap(); try my way.. a minor difference is there

Comment: still same blank screen nothing changed

Comment: something went wrong in Map Key then.. make sure that you are using the Map key for that app which is registered during the generation of the key..

Comment: if nothing worked out delete/(remove it from the location and keep a copy of it) your debug.keystore file clean your project which will generate a new copy of debug.keystore file and try giving SHA1 fingerprint of it and generate a new key

Comment: i did this step too :\ and nothing changed

Comment: Aditya one more question i created a project with googla map i worked very well and once the map become blank what that mean?

sure i'll tell but i'm really disappointed i think won't the solution

Comment: i did not get you.. but you'll definately come over this.. try and find other ways..