# Blank GoogleMap on a real Android 2.3 device

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display google map on android 2.3.
I followed the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api)

I am using android studio 0.3.7
I am getting a image similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615759/blank-googlemap-on-a-real-android-2-3-device-with-google-api-lv-17)

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.Greek.Market;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Manifest:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Greek.Market"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB86qZi7klht-Dvu9LhosHdw2ZRHq3OZxk"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Greek.Market.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


    <permission
        android:name="com.Greek.Market.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.Greek.Market.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

**build.grandle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

I deploy my app on a android device directly

From what i read, i think the problem is the api_key, but i don't know where...

I get SHA1 with the command:
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\Users\user\
.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Can someone help me? I am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

**1.** Remove this line from the XML layout file:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

**2.** From other portions of you code I haven't seen something wrong, So there maybe few  things you could do:

- Reproduce you key using the `API Console`, you can follow this blog post and make sure you do every thing right: [Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403), Make sure twice that you are turning on the right `API for Android`.
- If you did all this, and still see this problem, make sure you are removing the application complete from the phone before installing this all over again as the API key is cached until you remove the application.

Comment: Finally worked!!! The problem was the api_key. I created a new one, removed my app from the phone and it worked!!!
Thanks a lot