# Google Map showing Blank

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have Developed an application that have Google Map functionality so i use new google play services library but when i launch Google map activity its showing map but blank so what is wrong with my code

my manifest file xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.apa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity
            android:name="***************"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="*****.*****.***.ViewOnMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view_on_map" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value=*********************************" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
```

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

activity file

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_on_map);
    Global.startAppAd.loadAd();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


}
```

LogCat error

Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: check your `API Key` carefully

Comment: Check your LogCat, it should give you an error.

Comment: Also, do you have the correct SHA1 for your application?

Comment: Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: check you google map KEY

Comment: Is your device's time/date correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615759/blank-googlemap-on-a-real-android-2-3-device-with-google-api-lv-17/15636254#15636254

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your API key carefully
2. Check your `SHA key` carefully
3. You should be connected to internet using WIFI before first time using Google map  and wait 2-3 min till download map data etc. next time no need to connected with internet but if u want to search another location it must also be connected with internet using WIFI .

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the **LogCat error
Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).**

it seams its problem with Authentication. and Code should have 
        **googleMap = fm.getMap();**

```
// Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = fm.getMap();
```

Try to use this... And Double check SHA1 key

**EDIT** :

Check Phone Location settings also..

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- **Google Play Services:**

  You have to download the latest Google Play Services
     [com.android.vending-4.8.20.apk](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358540606).In that site if google play
     services wasn't working means you can find a lot of sites in
     internet named `com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk`.

  you can run the Google play Services by using the Command Prompt
     `adb install com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk`.

  **Note:** You have to download the latest Google play services because year by year latest version will be updated in internet.

Comment: issue in real time devices

Comment: @Pranav try to download that com.android.vending 4.8.20.apk and intall it.may be it will help you to resolve these isssue.

Comment: i check it in real time device so is it required..?

Comment: @Pranav I am also getting these same problem.map wasn't load and show these error.Then I try to use these apk to solve these issue.It will work in real devices also.

Comment: @amitsharma yes definitely