# Blank Google Map on MapsActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

when map is ready, in my MapsActivity.java, it do not show anything but just google logo and zoom control arrows.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(41.4538381,15.5532994);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    UiSettings mapSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324091/google-map-showing-blank

Comment: yes @cricket_007 I have seen several posts without success :(

Comment: @michael did you added your api keys correctly?

Comment: And did you read those? There are several questions saying the map is blank. The API key is most often the reason.

Comment: yes @MrunalAhirrao I set my keys into app/src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml and app/src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Comment: @michael you should also add api keys to manifest. using `<metadata>` tag and should also request permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.
   READ_GSERVICES" />`

Comment: @MrunalAhirrao metadata is already present.

Comment: @MrunalAhirrao also permission you suggested is present

Comment: Solved creating a new API key.