# My application won't run on an emulator but it will run on my phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying test my application on an emulator but it will not work. However, it works fine on my phone. I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with version 4.0.3. How do I create an emulator that will work with this?

These are the errors and here it is in pastebin http://pastebin.com/PR65kGxg:

```
03-05 15:03:16.777: W/Trace(856): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-05 15:03:16.967: W/Trace(856): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-05 15:03:16.967: W/Trace(856): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-05 15:03:17.387: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(856): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015
03-05 15:03:17.427: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(856): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015
03-05 15:03:17.467: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(856): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015
03-05 15:03:17.497: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(856): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015
03-05 15:03:17.527: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(856): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015
03-05 15:03:17.887: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(856): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015
03-05 15:03:17.887: D/AndroidRuntime(856): Shutting down VM
03-05 15:03:17.897: W/dalvikvm(856): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.neatspots/com.example.neatspots.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.neatspots.MainActivity.setMapDefaults(MainActivity.java:89)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.neatspots.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-05 15:03:17.917: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  ... 11 more
03-05 15:03:18.187: D/dalvikvm(856): GC_CONCURRENT freed 244K, 13% free 2530K/2892K, paused 8ms+71ms, total 260ms
03-05 15:03:37.127: I/Process(856): Sending signal. PID: 856 SIG: 9
```

This is line 89:

```
public void setMapDefaults()
{
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); //line 89
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it on the emulator? Does it crash? What's in the logcat?

Comment: What is the question? What is wrong with your emulator or how do set up an emulator?

Comment: What are your APIs in your manifest?

Comment: What are your minimum and target sdk versions of your application, as well as the api version on your emulator?

Comment: This is what I have in the manifest:     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />. I have tried different API versions on my emulator and it gives the error message in the emulator that the application has stopped working

Comment: Post the errors from the logcat on your emulator

Comment: could you please post the related code about this line: `MainActivity.setMapDefaults(MainActivity.java:89)`?

Comment: This sounds like bad news; _Google Play services out of date.  Requires 2012100 but found 1015_ especially the words "Requires"

Comment: This doesn't mean I have to start all over again does it? :S I'm half way through developing...

Comment: No- your code is fine. I suspect you should have a read of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar) - it sounds very similar. I am about to start using these new V2 Google Play Services so hopefully with a bit of an SDK update you'll be back on track.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the question on SO I was looking for

Comment: Good stuff. I added that as an answer in case that 100% answers your question as to why it wasn't working. The guidelines are a bit subjective as to what corresponds to a duplicate but from my first glance your issue *is* different to the linked question albeit they have the same cause and resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new virtual device and in target select Google API level 17 and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your app uses maps API so check if emulator has Google APIs 4.0 target, not a simple Android 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I had a read of the SO guidelines of duplicates and deemed this question different enough to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar) in order to merit an answer which states "this could be the same problem as this question" type answer/comment thing. Any moderators out feel free to tidy this up.

Basically- Jonathan's code is fine despite the NPE. It's likely the emulator-Google V2 Play Service compatibility issue.