# Support Fragment Manager always return null in google maps android version 2

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using this code from xamarin studio sample for showing google maps android version 2 in my project:

```
_mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment;
            if (_mapFragment == null)
            {
                GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
                    .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeSatellite)
                        .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(false)
                        .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

                FragmentTransaction fragTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                _mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
                fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.googleMap  , _mapFragment, "map");
                fragTx.Commit();
            }
```

and this is my layout

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/googleMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

but it always return null.

I run the sample of xamrin also. while it works fine ago. but now it is not working. No errors or exceptions. just `_mapFragment` is null.

from where could be this?

**EDIT**

I change the layout code to :

```
  <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/googleMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and the first line of code to this:

```
_mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById (Resource .Id.googleMap ) as SupportMapFragment;
```

now, the `FragmentManager` not returns null. but yet the map don't loaded but yet the fragment is a white page and not zooming out and zooming in works.

I use this code for getting map, but map fragment returns `null`:

```
private void SetupMapIfNeeded()
    {
        if (mapView == null)
        {
            mapView = _mapFragment.Map;
            if (mapView != null)
            {
                mapView .MapType =1;
                mapView .MyLocationEnabled = true ;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you added this? class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: I don't understand, added this where? I have not any code like what you write in the comment. where should add this?

Comment: in <fragment> as a attribute.

Comment: I'm going to add this to the <framelayout> but in the xamarin sample it defined like what I write above. And it was working for me some days ago, but I do not why it is not working now

Comment: i have not tried above code yet...but if you want some help regarding to other i will help you.

Comment: @Pratik really do you mean <framelayout> when you said <fragment> ?

Comment: no i mean only to fragment and i have implemented it successfully so i thought you might be missed something.

Comment: So I do not know how should add this? can you share some tutorials or some codes please?

Comment: you can find good tutorials here....http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/

Comment: wait i m going to post some of my working application code.

Comment: At what point are you programatically adding the fragment?

Comment: See my [example][1]. Hopefully that will get you moving in the right direction.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565460/error-opening-supportmapfragment-for-second-time/15813151?noredirect=1#comment26260060_15813151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you second problem:

> now, the FragmentManager not returns null. but yet the map don't loaded but yet the fragment is a white page and not zooming out and zooming in works.

This problem is usually derived from a problem in referencing `google-play-service` library.
Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps in your application, especially the first 3 steps:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

another cause of this could be that you haven't configured the Google API Console properly, so I suggest you to take a look at this guide as well:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

another reason that may cause this is if you have some kind of problem in your permissions in the manifest file. You can look at the first guide for the needed permissions as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think you should be right. Actually xamarin have specific way for reffering to google play libraries. he descripe it https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2 . porobably I have some problems by this. but I do not know. I re add the googleplayservices to propeject but ye the problem is live

Comment: Notice that, MAYBE THE GOOGLE MAP IS NOT AVAILABLE IN YOUR REGOIN(FOR EXAMPLE MIDDLE EAST COUNTRIES)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the key isn't correct. You can try the following thing:

- Be sure you use your right packet name like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16602590/2212742)
- allow using internet on manifest