# Failed to load Map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

```
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I am using Eclipse 4.2.2 with Android SDK Tools 22.01 and I have installed Google Play services (rev. 7), also I have imported google-play-services_lib into my workspace and added a reference to that to my android project.

Comment: where are you testing the application?

Comment: Could you find a solution for this issue? Please share....

Comment: have you found solution of this?

Comment: if somebody still looking answer, check here - the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17947755/1891118

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22653551/1318946