# Google Map is only showing a grey background and not the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm currently working on an app that uses the Google Maps API v2. But the MapView only displays a grey background, the Google logo and the zoom-buttons.

Here are the error messages:

```
10-27 10:50:25.309: D/REQUEST(18335): Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
10-27 10:50:25.309: D/REQUEST(18335): Open Connection
10-27 10:50:26.239: D/REQUEST(18335): DRD(24): 62|147
10-27 10:50:26.239: D/REQUEST(18335): Close
10-27 10:50:26.239: D/REQUEST(18335): Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@409cf570 not retrying
10-27 10:50:26.239: D/REQUEST(18335): Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@409b25b8
```

And another:

```
10-27 10:49:49.309: E/REQUEST(18335): In Error Mode
10-27 10:49:49.319: E/Google Maps Android API(18335): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

My Manifest does contain my API key and various permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.hobbit.xmltest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="de.hobbit.xmltest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="de.hobbit.xmltest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="SOMEKEY" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SingleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_single" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope someone can find my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't EVER post an API key! You can and should throw it away and generate a new one... It is like posting your password here!

Comment: Btw you should always target the latest API level in your manifest, not the same as your min sdk.

Comment: [Check if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491400/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-issue-with-android-google-ma)

Comment: Also make sure the package name is correctly set for the key...

Comment: @WarrenFaith okay, got it, no API keys here ;) the package name should be set correctly

Comment: @MysticMagic thanks, trying some things from there out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong keystore...

Instead of using the debug keystore, I used my actual keystore.

To access the debug keystore in eclipse

1.Go to Window->Preferences->Android->Build

2.Copy the SHA1 fingerprint

3.Generate an API key in the Developers Console using the debug keystore

Comment: This saved my day. Just wanted to add info for Android Studio users: you can access debug keystore at~/.android/debug.keystore. To read sha1, the following command can be used (assuming it is run under .android folder): keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore

Comment: how i can change gray color ?