# Map Fragment not working in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity

I've already tried a thousand configurations and codes, but my map activity insists in not working. Things I've tried:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

- enabled access permissions (INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, READ_GSERVICES etc);
- enabled OpenGL (android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" etc);
- supplied two keys (com.google.android.geo.API_KEY and com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY) with directly key in AndroidManifest and referencing that by xml values in debug and release folders (@string/map_api);
- tried to use map library (uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps");
- tried to include permission tag uses-permission (...permission.MAPS_RECEIVE);
- tried to inform services version (android:name="com.google.android.gms.version");
- tried to generate keys for a own certificate and android.keystore under .android folder;
- file:

  ```
  <manifest package="com.myapp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:anrdroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
      <application
              android:allowBackup="true"
              android:icon="@drawable/logo"
              android:label="@string/name"
              android:supportsRtl="true"
              android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
      android:theme="@style/Default">
          <meta-data
                  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                  android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
              <activity
                  android:name=".view.MainActivity"
                  android:icon="@drawable/logo"
                  android:label="@string/name">
                  <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                  </intent-filter>
              </activity>
              <activity
                  android:name=".view.ActivityMap"
                  android:icon="@drawable/logo_row"
                  android:label="@string/name">
              </activity>
              ...
          </application>
          </manifest>
  ```

**build.gradle**

- tried different compile and build configurations (23, 22, 19 etc);
- tried different library versions (8.4.0, 7.80 etc);
- tried different library versions for appcompat library (23.2.1, 22.2.1 etc);
- used selective compile only for maps and dependencies or Google Services complete;
- tried to sign debug and release with same and different keys;
- file:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.myapp"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 23
          versionCode 1
          versionName "0.0.1"
          multiDexEnabled true
      }

      signingConfigs {
          keystore {
              storeFile file("path_to_keystore")
              storePassword "my_password"
              keyAlias "my_key_alias"
              keyPassword "my_password"
          }
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
          }
      }

      packagingOptions {
          exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
          exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
          exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
          exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
      }

      dexOptions {
          javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
      compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:3.0.0'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4'
  }
  ```

**Code**

- tried to extends AppCompat, FragmentActivity;
- tried to request permission in api 6 using ActivityCompat.requestPermissions();
- tried call MapsInitializer.initialize() and check return;
- tried to use only fragment into layout file, informing context etc;
- tried to use fragment inside FragmentLayout;
- files:

  ```
  public class ActivityMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
  {
      private GoogleMap map;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
          SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activityMapID);
          fragment.getMapAsync(this);
      }


      @Override
      public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
      {
          map = googleMap;
          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-34, 151)).title("Marker in Sydney"));
      }
  }
  ```

activity_map.xml:

```
    <fragment android:id="@+id/activityMapID"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Others**

- checked my network connections and firewalls;
- checked if the keys were available and working in Google Console;
- tried to clean, rebuild project and invalidate caches for Android Studio many times;
- tried to wipe data, restart and clean device (and tested in more than one device);
- removed the app through adb using "adb shell pm clear  ...";
- no nullpointers, onMapReady returns a valid map and debugging code, everything works fine;
- if I create a new map app using Android Studio, everything works fine;

In first call, I have this log:

```
    03-21 09:34:28.478 25570-26174/com.myapp I/LoadedApk: connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.maps.auth.ApiTokenService
    03-21 09:34:29.770 25570-25570/com.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-21 09:34:30.020 25570-27391/com.myapp I/b: Sending API token request.
    03-21 09:34:30.090 25570-25633/com.myapp I/LoadedApk: connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService
    03-21 09:34:31.231 25570-27391/com.myapp I/b: Received API Token: AH0uPGGIx9Ygap4ZXq8T8vK7qcPxgyDi5NRIaIPyPauG4xWFn1lI7KQF9IuY2yqbpYMhWitKnTUiU-sZD9tFdJvr1naCVhz3c9APmLbueopuhcD6K5LHpZKnkYCQDEefhrTeGPNOR0fdz0QmC4WD8rkgQTbLmfbnOIA7cvZZBOmn7hFmcyavIVRQZlaY9_OLaPMFxIVFVBml / Expires in: 432000000ms
    03-21 09:34:31.241 25570-27391/com.myapp I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 431700 seconds.
    03-21 09:34:31.251 25570-27391/com.myapp I/d: Saved auth token
    03-21 09:34:31.832 25570-25582/com.myapp I/LoadedApk: connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.clearcut.service.ClearcutLoggerService
```

Then after second call, I have the message that my key is invalid:

```
    03-21 09:35:22.596 25570-25633/com.myapp I/LoadedApk: connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.clearcut.service.ClearcutLoggerService
    03-21 09:35:37.762 25570-25570/com.myapp I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 8703034
    03-21 09:35:37.973 25570-28472/com.myapp E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
    03-21 09:35:38.363 25570-25582/com.myapp I/LoadedApk: connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService
```

I really don't know what to do anymore. Does someone have any idea what could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491400/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-issue-with-android-google-ma


Another link:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667935/failed-to-load-map-error-contacting-google-servers-this-is-probably-an-authent

Comment: I assuming you are quite confused. As your other map app is working. You certainly missed some configuration while following the process in the current app.

Comment: The strange thing is if I call directly my map activity from manifest as the launcher, it works fine. When I call it from another activity, doesn't work. I'm still trying to figure out some permission problem...

Comment: Did you put correct map API key??

Comment: Yes, and I tried with more than just one key. I've tried with the generated android.keystore and my own. None of them worked...  :(

Comment: If you checking it in real device, Once uninstall your app from the device and clean your project and run again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

In another part of my code, I was calling

```
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

To simplify all the calls I do for HTTPS. The issue was when Google Maps tried to call its server: it was using the same SSL Context I've set before so it couldn't connect on Map servers.

I've just commented that line and changed my code to:

```
    URLConnection urlConn = new URL(myAddress).openConnection();
    HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConn;
    https.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

and everything worked like magic!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line at the end of the `build.radle`

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Add it in inside of `manifest` tag :

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>
```

Comment: Make sure your API key is generated with SHA-1 key + package name mentioned in the android manifest file not but your actual source package