# Not able to display google map for google example code

Tags: android, android-maps

i encountered google map cannot loading issue for 2 weeks, but still pending here.

i imported to source code and add google-play-services_lib to lib

sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps
sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Using google API 17 and google source code, but emulator not display anything

http://dl2.iteye.com/upload/attachment/0085/3047/48240d53-5091-37c3-9cca-174feb6815c6.gif
http://dl2.iteye.com/upload/attachment/0085/3049/79986c6a-acb6-39c9-abe4-c43ed27e8f2a.gif

log

```
06-01 10:49:50.558: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:49:50.808: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 314 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:49:50.838: D/gralloc_goldfish(1955): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 06-01 10:49:51.078: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 136 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:49:51.863: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:50:09.360: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 232 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:50:10.338: D/dalvikvm(1955): GC_CONCURRENT freed 125K, 10% free 2707K/2976K, paused 7ms+64ms, total 406ms
 06-01 10:50:14.528: D/dalvikvm(1955): GC_CONCURRENT freed 265K, 13% free 2829K/3236K, paused 76ms+6ms, total 414ms
 06-01 10:50:14.728: E/Google Maps Android API(1955): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
 06-01 10:50:15.848: D/dalvikvm(1955): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 12% free 3015K/3404K, paused 71ms+82ms, total 244ms
 06-01 10:50:16.158: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:50:16.648: D/libEGL(1955): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
 06-01 10:50:16.658: D/libEGL(1955): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so 
06-01 10:50:16.848: I/Choreographer(1955): Skipped 718 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-01 10:50:17.588: D/dalvikvm(1955): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 257K, 14% free 3085K/3576K, paused 49ms, total 59ms
```

Comment: Try this way. Just remove both library from your project and added into google_play_service_lib project.

Comment: NOT working, it seem only is used on device

Answer (score 0):

While using Android Map Api v2, you can't run  it on Android emulator; you must use a device for your tests.

[follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332)

Comment: i saw some video from youtube,i though we don't need

Answer (score 0):

Test using your Mobile instead your emulator, because the error is
"Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer."
And it must support openGl version 2.0 or above.