# Android Maps v2: "Google Play services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device."

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have an application that need Google Play Services, because i'm using Android Maps v2.

I'm running some tests, and one test requires factory reset the device, and try to run the application.

The first time i do this, without connect wifi or any internet source, the message that appears on map is:

[image: Google Play Services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device.]

When i click on this "OK" button, my application crash. The log:

[image: Error Log]

When i connect to internet, this message change, and the button that show is "Update", then i just click and all works as expected.

Can i handle this event on Ok Button? Ny tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i created one emulator with google api instead of android.
and now, the message is to update the google play services.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar)

EDIT
Now I'm using [this emulator](http://genymotion.com) instead the eclipse android emulator. Genymotion is faster and better.

Comment: I guess its not the eclipse emulator but a Google provided emulator which we get along with the Android SDK package. Eclipse only integrates itself with with.